# Getting the class name of an instance

Tags: python, introspection, instanceof, python-datamodel

How do I find out the name of the class used to create an instance of an object in Python?

I'm not sure if I should use the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module or parse the `__class__` attribute.

Comment: What exactly are you 'parsing' from the __class__ variable?

Comment: the top-level name of the class that the instance belongs to (without module name, etc...)

Answer (score 2540, accepted):

Have you tried the [`__name__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) of the class? ie `type(x).__name__` will give you the name of the class, which I think is what you want.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.count(0)
>>> type(x).__name__
'count'
```

If you're still using Python 2, note that the above method works with [new-style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass) only (in Python 3+ all classes are "new-style" classes). Your code might use some old-style classes. The following works for both:

```
x.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Amazingly simple. Wonder why `dir(x.__class__)` does not list it?

Comment: Why use `__class__` over the `type` method? Like so: `type(x).__name__`. Isn't calling double underscore members directly discouraged? I can't see a way around using `__name__`, though.

Comment: You have to use ````__class__```` directly to be compatible with old-style classes, since their type is just ````instance````.

Comment: Since I'm using this is in a `__getattr__` method, if I seek any attributes on `self`, I get a recursion error.  Using `type` was of utmost importance in that situation.

Comment: This is used often enough in logging, orm and framework code that there really should be a builtin typename(x) ... requiring a user to look at the "guts" to get a __name__ isn't terribly pythonic, IMO.

Comment: @ErikAronesty, `def typename(x): return type(x).__name__`

Comment: So, I have tried both these solutions on a case where they do not perform as I would expect or wish. ``RandomOverSampler`` from the ``imblearn`` package is a class deriving from a series of parents where one of which is defined as ``SamplerMixin(BaseEstimator, metaclass=ABCMeta)``. In this case, both of the proposed methods return ``ABCMeta`` on an instance of ``RandomOverSampler`` (or the analogous ``RandomUnderSampler`` class) while I was looking for a convenient way to distinguish between these objects at runtime. Any idea on how to get the *actual* class name?

Comment: @jpmc26 [They can be different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633356/4518341).

Comment: @Bobort Couldn't you just use `super().__getattr__(self, '__class__')`?

Comment: @Bobort I remember reading somewhere that, for efficiency, dunder attributes don't work with custom `__getattr__`, so you wouldn't get a recursion error. Not sure tho.

Comment: `getattr(model_type, "__name__")` easy and safe to call. No need to potentially call missing properties, no need to create new defs, no need to call `__class__`. This is even for a generic type defined as `model_typeT = T.TypeVar("model_typeT")` and passed in as an argument: `self, *, model_type: model_typeT, filter: BaseFilter`. The model is `class FSBaseModel(BaseModel): ...` and if you print inside this method the value of `getattr(obj, "__name__")` on the model type that inherits from it, e.g. `class MyModel(FSBaseModel): ...` you'll see `MyModel`

Answer (score 546):

Do you want the name of the class as a string?

```
instance.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Or instance.__class__ to get the class object :D

Comment: Is it safe to use double underscore properties?

Comment: @EduardLuca why wouldn't it be safe? Built-in properties use underscores so that they do not cause any conflict with the code you write

Comment: Well I know that single underscores mean / suggest that the method / property should be private (although you can't really implement private methods in Python AFAIK), and I was wondering if that's not the case with (some) double underscores too.

Comment: @EduardLuca Double underscores at the start only are similar to a single underscore at the start, but even more "private" (look up "python name mangling"). Double underscores at beginning *and end* are different - those are reserved for python and are not private (e.g. magic methods like \_\_init__ and \_\_add__).

Comment: Or if you doing this from inside the class this will work `self.__class__.__name__`

Comment: A shorter solution is `type(instance).__name__`.

Comment: This is what I needed for a utility to create a logger for classes without having a string literal.

Answer (score 183):

[`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) ?

```
>>> class A:
...     def whoami(self):
...         print(type(self).__name__)
...
>>>
>>> class B(A):
...     pass
...
>>>
>>>
>>> o = B()
>>> o.whoami()
'B'
>>>
```

Comment: I like this one. This way, it is possible in a base class to get the name of the subclass.

Comment: or `self.__class__.__name__` instead of `type(self).__name__` to get the same behaviour. Unless there is something the `type()` function does that I am not aware of?

Comment: If you're using `type(item)` on a list item the result will be `<type 'instance'>` while `item.__class__.__name__` holds the class name.

Comment: I think the issue that @Grochni mentions is only relevant for certain classes in Python 2.x, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666856/why-does-typemyfield-return-type-instance-and-not-type-field

Comment: @andreb The original solution is shorter.

Answer (score 51):

```
class A:
  pass

a = A()
str(a.__class__)
```

The sample code above (when input in the interactive interpreter) will produce `'__main__.A'` as opposed to `'A'` which is produced if the `__name__` attribute is invoked. By simply passing the result of `A.__class__` to the `str` constructor the parsing is handled for you. However, you could also use the following code if you want something more explicit.

```
"{0}.{1}".format(a.__class__.__module__,a.__class__.__name__)
```

This behavior can be preferable if you have classes with the same name defined in separate modules.

**The sample code provided above was tested in Python 2.7.5.**

Answer (score 30):

In Python 2,

```
type(instance).__name__ != instance.__class__.__name__
# if class A is defined like
class A():
   ...

type(instance) == instance.__class__
# if class A is defined like
class A(object):
  ...
```

Example:

```
>>> class aclass(object):
...   pass
...
>>> a = aclass()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.aclass'>
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.aclass'>
>>>
>>> type(a).__name__
'aclass'
>>>
>>> a.__class__.__name__
'aclass'
>>>


>>> class bclass():
...   pass
...
>>> b = bclass()
>>>
>>> type(b)
<type 'instance'>
>>> b.__class__
<class __main__.bclass at 0xb765047c>
>>> type(b).__name__
'instance'
>>>
>>> b.__class__.__name__
'bclass'
>>>
```

Comment: This only holds true for old Python 2.x. In 3.x, bclass() would resolve to bclass(object). And even then, new classes appeared in Python 2.2.

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively you can use the `classmethod` decorator:

```python
class A:
    @classmethod
    def get_classname(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    def use_classname(self):
        return self.get_classname()
```

**Usage**:

```python
>>> A.get_classname()
'A'
>>> a = A()
>>> a.get_classname()
'A'
>>> a.use_classname()
'A'
```

Answer (score 17):

Apart from grabbing the special [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__name__) attribute, you might find yourself in need of the [qualified name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) for a given class/function. This is done by grabbing the types `__qualname__`.

In most cases, these will be exactly the same, but, when dealing with nested classes/methods these differ in the output you get. For example:

```
class Spam:
    def meth(self):
        pass
    class Bar:
        pass

>>> s = Spam()
>>> type(s).__name__ 
'Spam'
>>> type(s).__qualname__
'Spam'
>>> type(s).Bar.__name__       # type not needed here
'Bar'
>>> type(s).Bar.__qualname__   # type not needed here 
'Spam.Bar'
>>> type(s).meth.__name__
'meth'
>>> type(s).meth.__qualname__
'Spam.meth'
```

Since introspection is what you're after, this is always you might want to consider.

Comment: Should be noted that `__qualname__` is for Python 3.3+

Comment: And I would avoid naming anything in my software "meth".

Comment: Related explanation for `__qualname__` vs `__name__`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108488/what-is-qualname-in-python

Answer (score 16):

Good question.

Here's a simple example based on GHZ's which might help someone:

```
>>> class person(object):
        def init(self,name):
            self.name=name
        def info(self)
            print "My name is {0}, I am a {1}".format(self.name,self.__class__.__name__)
>>> bob = person(name='Robert')
>>> bob.info()
My name is Robert, I am a person
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use `__qualname__` which stands for qualified name of a function or class

Example:

```
>>> class C:
...     class D:
...         def meth(self):
...             pass
...
>>> C.__qualname__
'C'
>>> C.D.__qualname__
'C.D'
>>> C.D.meth.__qualname__
'C.D.meth'
```

documentation link [**qualname**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name)

Comment: this gives the name of a class not the  class name of an instance

Comment: This was already suggested by @Dimitris in 2017

Answer (score 8):

To get instance classname:

```py
type(instance).__name__
```

or

```py
instance.__class__.__name__
```

both are the same

Comment: [Actually they can be different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060499/4518341) if the class overrides `__class__`, or in old style classes (which are obsolete)

Answer (score 1):

You can first use `type` and then `str` to extract class name from it.

```py
class foo:pass;

bar:foo=foo();
print(str(type(bar))[8:-2][len(str(type(bar).__module__))+1:]);
```

### Result

```
foo
```

Comment: That's hard to read, are those inline methods I don't know about?

Comment: If I came across a line such as this, I'd definitely "annotate" the code just to know the name of whom I was going to swear a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to solve this for a list (or iterable collection) of objects, here's how I would solve:

```py
from operator import attrgetter

# Will use a few data types to show a point
my_list = [1, "2", 3.0, [4], object(), type, None]

# I specifically want to create a generator
my_class_names = list(map(attrgetter("__name__"), map(type, my_list))))

# Result:
['int', 'str', 'float', 'list', 'object', 'type', 'NoneType']


# Alternatively, use a lambda
my_class_names = list(map(lambda x: type(x).__name__, my_list))
```