# Difference between type(obj) and obj.__class__

Tags: python, new-style-class

What is the difference between `type(obj)` and `obj.__class__`? Is there ever a possibility of `type(obj) is not obj.__class__`?

I want to write a function that works generically on the supplied objects, using a default value of 1 in the same type as another parameter.  Which variation, #1 or #2 below, is going to do the right thing?

```
def f(a, b=None):
  if b is None:
    b = type(a)(1) # #1
    b = a.__class__(1) # #2
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`type(obj)` and `type.__class__` do not behave the same for old style classes in Python 2:

```
>>> class a(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class b(a):
...     pass
... 
>>> class c:
...     pass
... 
>>> ai = a()
>>> bi = b()
>>> ci = c()
>>> type(ai) is ai.__class__
True
>>> type(bi) is bi.__class__
True
>>> type(ci) is ci.__class__
False
>>> type(ci)
<type 'instance'>
>>> ci.__class__
<class __main__.c at 0x7f437cee8600>
```

This is explained [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#newstyle):

> For an old-style class, the statement `x.__class__` provides the class of *x*, but `type(x)` is always `<type 'instance'>`. This reflects the fact that all old-style instances, independent of their class, are implemented with a single built-in type, called `instance`.

Answer (score 80):

This is an old question, but none of the answers seems to mention that. in the general case, it **IS** possible for a new-style class to have different values for `type(instance)` and `instance.__class__`:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def display(self):
        print("ClassA")

class ClassB(object):
    __class__ = ClassA

    def display(self):
        print("ClassB")

instance = ClassB()

print(type(instance))
print(instance.__class__)
instance.display()
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.ClassB'>
<class '__main__.ClassA'>
ClassB
```

The reason is that `ClassB` is overriding the `__class__` descriptor, however the internal type field in the object is not changed. `type(instance)` reads directly from that type field, so it returns the correct value, whereas `instance.__class__` refers to the new descriptor replacing the original descriptor provided by Python, which reads the internal type field. Instead of reading that internal type field, it returns a hardcoded value.

Comment: _Caveat lector_: this should be taken as an example of why you should avoid overriding `__class__`! You may cause code down the line that uses `__class__` to break.

Comment: Also affected by `__getattribute__`, which intercepts the request for `OBJ.__class__` but not for `type(OBJ)`.

Comment: Some code does this deliberately to lie about the type of objects, such as `weakref.proxy`. Some people think `obj.__class__` should be preferred, because it believes the lie, while some people think `type(obj)` should be preferred because it ignores the lie. `isinstance` will return true if an object's real class or its lie class is an instance of the second argument.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson This mainly shows why magic `__` properties should NOT be override-able in the first place ...

Comment: Important to notice here is that: assigning the `__class__` attribute in an _instance_ **will** effectively change its type, and class "for real" (including changing "type" and "isinstance" responses after the fact)

Answer (score 35):

Old-style classes are the problem, sigh:

```
>>> class old: pass
... 
>>> x=old()
>>> type(x)
<type 'instance'>
>>> x.__class__
<class __main__.old at 0x6a150>
>>>
```

Not a problem in Python 3 since all classes are new-style now;-).

In Python 2, a class is new-style only if it inherits from another new-style class (including `object` and the various built-in types such as `dict`, `list`, `set`, ...) or implicitly or explicitly sets `__metaclass__` to `type`.

Comment: It's Python 3 time, which *should* we use?

Comment: If your code is following best practice as described by Alex, `type()` would be preferable. In Python 3, it is always following best practice, so use type() in Python 3.

Comment: @AaronHall Would I be correct for me to assume that using `type()` is also preferred over `__class__` if I am writing Python 2 code where I know that it will only be called with instances of new-style classes?

Comment: @kasperd Yes, if your code always inherits from object, you're safe using `type()`.

Comment: @Alex Martelli @AaronHall The built-in function `type(instance)` and the attribute `instance.__class__` can be different, even with [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), as Guido mentioned in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#the-abc-module-an-abc-support-framework): "Also, `isinstance(x, B)` is equivalent to `issubclass(x.__class__, B) or issubclass(type(x), B)`. (It is possible `type(x)` and `x.__class__` are not the same object, e.g. when `x` is a proxy object.)" and as @Flavien's answer illustrated.

Answer (score 6):

There's an interesting edge case with proxy objects (that use weak references):

```py
>>> import weakref
>>> class MyClass:
...     x = 42
... 
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj_proxy = weakref.proxy(obj)
>>> obj_proxy.x  # proxies attribute lookup to the referenced object
42
>>> type(obj_proxy)  # returns type of the proxy 
weakproxy
>>> obj_proxy.__class__  # returns type of the referenced object
__main__.MyClass
>>> del obj  # breaks the proxy's weak reference
>>> type(obj_proxy)  # still works
weakproxy
>>> obj_proxy.__class__  # fails
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI - Django does this.

```
>>> from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
>>> type(default_storage)
django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage
>>> default_storage.__class__
django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage
```

As someone with finite cognitive capacity who's just trying to figure out what's going in order to get work done... it's frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a more understanding of the differences:
Summary:
classA.one, self.**class**.one and type(obj).one are the same.
self.one and obj.one are the same and they are distinct per instance.

```
class classA:

    one = "One"

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.__class__.one = val

    def show(self, marker):
        print("{}: self.one= {}, self.__class__.one= {}, classA.one= {}, type(self).one = {}".format(marker, self.one, self.__class__.one, classA.one, type(self).one))


one = classA('A')

one.show('One')

two = classA('B')
two.one = 'C'

two.show('Two')
print("{}".format(type(two).one))

three = classA('C')
classA.one = 'D'
three.one = 'E'
three.__class__.one = 'F'
three.show('Three')
two.show('Two')
one.show('One')
```

```
One: self.one= A, self.__class__.one= A, classA.one= A, type(self).one = A
Two: self.one= C, self.__class__.one= B, classA.one= B, type(self).one = B
B
Three: self.one= E, self.__class__.one= F, classA.one= F, type(self).one = F
Two: self.one= C, self.__class__.one= F, classA.one= F, type(self).one = F
One: self.one= F, self.__class__.one= F, classA.one= F, type(self).one = F
```