# double equals vs is in python

Tags: python, comparison, boolean, equals, equality

I run the following in the Python interpreter:

```python
>>> foo = 10
>>> dir(foo) == dir(10)
True
>>> dir(foo) is dir(10)
False
>>>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

`is` checks that 2 arguments refer to the same object, `==` checks that 2 arguments have the same value.  `dir()` returns a `list` which contains the same data for both `foo` and `10`, but the actual `list` instances for the 2 things are different.

Comment: A good example is 1==True returns True, but 1 is True returns False.

Comment: An even more directly relevant point is that `dir(10) is dir(10)` won't even be `True` (barring some sort of interpreter optimization), while `dir(1) == dir(10)` will be `True`.

Comment: You can say that "is" in python is the same to "===" in other languages like PHP.

Comment: This probably belongs in a separate question, but are numbers objects in python?  How come `1 is 1` returns `True` ?

Comment: @frank Yes, integers are objects.  Try `type(1)` or `a = 1;a.__class__` etc.  You'd have to get in to pretty deep internals of the parser to understand fully what integers have what identities (there's some interning, and other singleton-driven optimization going on if memory serves), but suffice to say 2 expressions composed of integer literals can sometimes be the same object and sometimes not.  For example, at least in my Python 3.6, `1 is 1` and `a = 1;b = 1;a is b` are both `True` but `1 is 10 / 10` is `False`.