# Check key exist in python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the file output:

```
apples:20
orange:100
```

Below is the code:

```
d = {}
with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
                continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == 'apples':
         v = v.strip()
         if v == 20:
             print "Apples are equal to 20"
         else:
             print "Apples may have greater than or less than 20"   
    if k == 'orrange':
         v = v.strip()
         if v == 20:
            print "orange are equal to 100"
         else:
            print "orange may have greater than or less than 100"
```

In above code i am written "if k == 'orrange':", but its actually "orange" as per output file.

In this case I have to print orrange key is not exist in output file. Please help me. How to do this

Comment: Don't *iterate over a dictionary to check if a key exists*. That defeats the *whole point*. Just use `if k in d: print("the key", k, "exists and the value is", d[k])`

Comment: Also, note, your value will be `str`, which you seem to be aware because you use `v = v.strip()`,  so `if v == 20` will *never be true*. Use `if int(v) == 20`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I thought `==` would coerce and yield expected result for `v==20`.

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ No, python never coerces. Python != Javascript

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To test, I ran `1 == True` and it returns `True`, but `1 is True` returns `False`. Python does low-level coercion in case of `==` operator, more discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python).

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ No, it does not. `1 == True` because `isinstance(True, int)` in python, booleans *are ints*

Comment: @CᴴᴀZ in the end, `==` will do whatever `__eq__` tells it to do.

Answer (score 60):

Use the `in` keyword.

```
if 'apples' in d:
    if d['apples'] == 20:
        print('20 apples')
    else:
        print('Not 20 apples')
```

If you want to get the value only if the key exists (and avoid an exception trying to get it if it doesn't), then you can use the `get` function from a dictionary, passing an optional default value as the second argument (if you don't pass it it returns `None` instead):

```
if d.get('apples', 0) == 20:
    print('20 apples.')
else:
    print('Not 20 apples.')
```

Comment: I want to print v value as well for some reasons. will above script will work in that case?

Comment: Since python evaluates Boolean conditions lazily, you can simplify your 'if' statement to look like this:
`if 'apples' in d and d['apples'] == 20: ...`.
The interpreter will check for the 'apples' key in the dictionary, and only if it exists will the interpreter continue to fetch it.