# Difference between == and is operator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("enter your age")
age = int(input())
if age < 21:
    print("no beer")
if age > 21:
    print("what beer do you like?")
    beer = input()
if beer is "union":
    print("this is water")
```

After typing union to answer nothing happens. Why? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: See also: [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python), [String comparison in Python: is vs. ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs), [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Comment: The odd thing is that if you set `beer = "union"` then the code work as expected (maybe because Python caches/reuses immutable objects?). However, getting the string from `input` produces a different object.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things wrong here:

You check for `age < 21` and `age > 21`, but what happens if I'm exactly 21 years old? You'll want to change the `>` to `>=` in order to catch this case (assuming you're in America where the drinking age is 21 and over).

Another thing I noticed. What happens if I'm not over 21?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "beer.py", line 8, in <module>
    if beer is "union":
NameError: name 'beer' is not defined
```

Oops. You've defined `beer`, but this condition is never reached if you're not over 21. Therefore when you reference `beer` in your last `if` statement, the interpreter has no idea what you're talking about. You'll want to move the last `if` inside the second one:

```
if age > 21:
    print("what beer do you like?")
    beer = input()
    if beer is "union":
        print("this is water")
```

Lastly, it's not a wise idea to use `is` as  a substitute for the `==` operator, because they are not equivalent. In this case, `beer is "union"` evaluates to False, whereas `beer == "union"` does not, but there are some cases where the two statements are functionally equivalent. For example:

```
$ python -i
>>> x = 3
>>> if x is 3:
...     print('x is 3!')
...
x is 3!
```

Therefore, your final code would look like this:

```
print("enter your age")
age = int(input())
if age < 21:
    print("no beer")
if age >= 21:
    print("what beer do you like?")
    beer = input()
    if beer == "union":
        print("this is water")
```

Edit: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python) for why they are not equivalent. `is` checks that they are the same object, whereas `==` checks that the values are equivalent (which is what you want).

Comment: The `is` operator checks for identity in Python. The `beer` variable and the string `"union"` are different objects in memory. Therefore, `is` will never return true.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Actually, `is` will often return `True`, it appears that immutable objects are reused in some situations (albeit not with `input`).

Comment: @JaredGoguen: I meant in this situation

Comment: @Jacobm001 `is` implies `equality` but the converse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for the "is" operator:

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true
>   if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object.

Just change your 2nd last line to

```
if beer == "union":
```

The code would work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an obvious bug in your code, the test `if beer is "union"`, which should be `if beer == "union"`, is not under the `age > 21` check.

That is, if `age < 21` the `beer` check will still happen, and `beer` will be undefined, raising an exception.

> NameError: name 'beer' is not defined

This is a bit more sane:

```
if age < 21:
    print("no beer")
if age > 21:
    print("what beer do you like?")
    beer = input()
    if beer is "union":
        print("this is water")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this picture will illustrate clearly about the difference between "is" and "==".

[image]