# Pandas .isna() while looping not being picked up

Tags: python, pandas

I am looping through some data, and if the column doesn't contain any NaNs I want to merge this with my master `df`. But for some reason, `.isna().any()` doesn't work in the loop, only when I look at the column separately.

My code currently is:

```
if df[Stock].isna().any() is False:
    total_df = total_df.merge(df[['Date', Stock]], on='Date', how='left')
else:
    pass
```

As far as I'm concerned this should filter out any columns containing NaNs. However, it doesn't, it basically appears to do nothing as my `df` once it's finished contains columns of NaNs as well as the columns I actually want. I have also tried `==True`, but to no avail. When I check a column that I know for a fact has NaNs in it using `print(df[Stock].isna().any())` the program quite rightly returns `True`. So my question is why won't this work in a loop?

I've been starring at this for hours now and it's possible I'm doing something incredibly stupid so a fresh pair of eyes might be whats needed but I'm really stumped. Cheers

EDIT:

So for what it's worth, when I do the sum of each column with NaNs in, it returns an actual number. So it appears pandas isn't recognising what are quite clearly `nan`s when I check the `df` manually. However, I have to do `pd.to_numeric` on my `df` data before performing the loop other wise I can't do any maths on the price data at a later stage. Is it possible this is affecting things?

Comment: what is `total_df` before the loop?

Comment: Apologies, `total_df` begins as an empty `df` with just a `Date` column, then I loop through to populate it

Comment: Actually, if you want to merge columns which do **not** contains any `NaN` value, you should look for columns where `if df[Stock].isna().any() is False`. Or `if not df[Stock].isna().any()`.

Comment: Sorry yes, I've completely ballsed this question up, I have been trying `is False` I changed it to True so see how it responded and mistakenly copy/pasted that. Will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is the use of `is`.

```
df[Stock].isna().any() is False:
```

it result always False and nothing is merged. But if you use:

```
if not df[col].isna().any():
```

or

```
df[Stock].isna().any() == False:
```

it works.

The reason is detailed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python). `is` is not equal to `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code I can't test it, but try putting this code inside a for loop. Not sure if ['Date', 'column'] should be with or without quotes, but try both.

```
for column in df:
    if df[column].isna().any() is False:
        total_df = total_df.merge(df[['Date', 'column']], on='Date', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate, but that adds nothing to the total_df at all now. I think I'm just going to have to stick all the data in and then do `dropna` and `axis=1` although I'd love to know why a simple condition like that doesn't work