# How do I get my function to differentiate between input 'I' and 'II' in python?

Tags: python-3.x, roman-numerals

My goal is to get the user to input two roman numerals between I and V and to add them together. I want to display the equation in both decimal values and their roman numeral equivalents.

However, when ever I put values other than I and V, the value gets assigned 'NoneType', and program fails. I've tried setting the returns to str() and then calling int() later, setting roman num is '': num_value = # and then returning num_value at the end, but none of it has worked.

I think I'm missing something very fundamental, and it has to do with differentiating between values with repeating characters, such as 'I' (which is ok) and 'II' which gets assigned NoneType.

```
firstNumeral = input("please enter a roman numeral between I and V: ")
secondNumeral = input('please enter a second roman numeral between I and V: ')
def get_user_num(roman_num):
    if roman_num is 'I':
        return int(1)
    elif roman_num is 'II':
        return int(2)
    elif roman_num is 'III':
        return int(3)
    elif roman_num is 'IV':
        return int(4)
    elif roman_num is 'V':
        return int(5)
    elif roman_num is 'VI':
        return int(6)
    elif roman_num is 'VII':
        return int(7)
    elif roman_num is 'VIII':
        return int(8)
    elif roman_num is 'IX':
        return int(9)
    elif roman_num is 'X':
        return int(10)
firstNumber = get_user_num(firstNumeral)
secondNumber = get_user_num(secondNumeral)
totalNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber
def get_roman_number(result_number):
    if result_number == 1:
        return "I"
    elif result_number == 2:
        return "II"
    elif result_number == 3:
        return 'III'
    elif result_number == 4:
        return 'IV'
    elif result_number == 5:
        return 'V'
    elif result_number == 6:
        return 'VI'
    elif result_number == 7:
        return 'VII'
    elif result_number == 8:
        return 'VIII'
    elif result_number == 9:
        return 'IX'
    elif result_number == 10:
        return 'X'
totalNumeral = get_roman_number(totalNumber)
print('Decimal values {} + {} = {}'.format(firstNumber,secondNumber, totalNumber))
print('Roman Numeral values {} + {} = {}'.format(firstNumeral, secondNumeral, totalNumeral))
```

when using any values other than I and V i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ... line 26, in <module>
    totalNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'''
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation in your code?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `is` to compare strings. Use `==`. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @DavidBuck i did, my apologies- first time using this website

Comment: `is` is NOT the same as `==`, as psuedo code and python is...

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse That did it. thank you.

Comment: @khelwood thanks a lot

Comment: @iTheSailor Consider using a dictionary for this instead of two different functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
firstNumeral = input("please enter a roman numeral between I and V: ")
secondNumeral = input('please enter a second roman numeral between I and V: ')
def get_user_num(roman_num):
    if roman_num is 'I':
        return int(1)
    elif roman_num == 'II':
        return int(2)
    elif roman_num == 'III':
        return int(3)
    elif roman_num == 'IV':
        return int(4)
    elif roman_num == 'V':
        return int(5)
    elif roman_num is 'VI':
        return int(6)
    elif roman_num == 'VII':
        return int(7)
    elif roman_num == 'VIII':
        return int(8)
    elif roman_num == 'IX':
        return int(9)
    elif roman_num == 'X':
        return int(10)
firstNumber = get_user_num(firstNumeral)
secondNumber = get_user_num(secondNumeral)
print(secondNumber)
totalNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber
def get_roman_number(result_number):
    if result_number == 1:
        return "I"
    elif result_number == 2:
        return "II"
    elif result_number == 3:
        return 'III'
    elif result_number == 4:
        return 'IV'
    elif result_number == 5:
        return 'V'
    elif result_number == 6:
        return 'VI'
    elif result_number == 7:
        return 'VII'
    elif result_number == 8:
        return 'VIII'
    elif result_number == 9:
        return 'IX'
    elif result_number == 10:
        return 'X'
totalNumeral = get_roman_number(totalNumber)
print('Decimal values {} + {} = {}'.format(firstNumber,secondNumber, totalNumber))
print('Roman Numeral values {} + {} = {}'.format(firstNumeral, secondNumeral, totalNumeral))
```

use '==' to check condition
[image]

Comment: as khelwood and Error - Syntactical Remorse commented, this solved my issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong with your `get_user_num(roman_num)` function, as already mentioned you need to use "==" instead of is.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008404/8426559

Also you have no fail-safes, so None will be returned if user types something illegal, which will break your code. A quick fix for this could be adding the line `return get_user_num(input("please enter a roman numeral between I and V: "))` at the end of the function:

```
def get_user_num(roman_num):
    if roman_num == 'I':
        return int(1)
    if roman_num == 'II':
        return int(2)
    if roman_num == 'III':
        return int(3)
    if roman_num == 'IV':
        return int(4)
    if roman_num == 'V':
        return int(5)
    if roman_num == 'VI':
        return int(6)
    if roman_num == 'VII':
        return int(7)
    if roman_num == 'VIII':
        return int(8)
    if roman_num == 'IX':
        return int(9)
    if roman_num == 'X':
        return int(10)
    return get_user_num(input("please enter a roman numeral between I and V: "))
```

You can also use `if` instead of `elif` because the function will return if any condition is met. Though, I'd suggest a cleaner approach with a more robust algorithm for this if you plan on scaling up beyond 10.