# Python. Check if input is same as a requrie struct

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to check if the input string is same as requirement struct?
Struct: `Number,Number Letter Number, Number`

For example:

```
if input is '12,9b7,23'
return True

if input is '1b' 
return faluse
```

Comment: Try regex. https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html

Comment: this is not even a syntactically correct `if` statement. You might want to do some tutorials: [if-statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) and then read about the differences between `is` and `==` [double-equals-vs-is-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html this sovled

```
\d{0,9},\d{0,9}[adc]\d{0,9},\d{0,9}
```