# Python type() or __class__, == or is

Tags: python, language-features

I want to test whether an object is an instance of a class, and only this class (no subclasses). I could do it either with:

```
obj.__class__ == Foo
obj.__class__ is Foo
type(obj) == Foo
type(obj) is Foo
```

Are there reasons to choose one over another? (performance differences, pitfalls, etc)

In other words: a) is there any practical difference between using `__class__` and `type(x)`? b) are class objects always safe for comparison using `is`?

---

**Update:** Thanks all for the feedback. I'm still puzzled by whether or not class objects are singletons, my common sense says they are, but it's been really hard to get a confirmation (try googling for "python", "class" and "unique" or "singleton").

I'd also like to clarify that, for my particular needs, the "cheaper" solution that just works is the best, since I'm trying to optimize the most out of a few, specialized classes (almost reaching the point where the sensible thing to do is to drop Python and develop that particular module in C). But the reason behind the question was to understand better the language, since some of its features are a bit too obscure for me to find that information easily. That's why I'm letting the discussion extend a little instead of settling for `__class__ is`, so I can hear the opinion of more experienced people. So far it's been very fruitful!

I ran a small test to benchmark the performance of the 4 alternatives. The profiler results were:

```
               Python  PyPy (4x)
type()    is   2.138   2.594
__class__ is   2.185   2.437
type()    ==   2.213   2.625
__class__ ==   2.271   2.453
```

Unsurprisingly, `is` performed better than `==` for all cases. `type()` performed better in Python (2% faster) and `__class__` performed better in PyPy (6% faster). Interesting to note that `__class__ ==` performed better in PyPy than `type() is`.

---

**Update 2:** many people don't seem to understand what I mean with "a class is a singleton", so I'll ilustrate with an example:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> X = Foo
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> X == Foo
False
>>> isinstance(X(), Foo)
False
>>> isinstance(Foo(), X)
False

>>> x = type('Foo', (object,), dict())
>>> y = type('Foo', (object,), dict())
>>> x == y
False
>>> isinstance(x(), y)
False

>>> y = copy.copy(x)
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
True
>>> isinstance(x(), y)
True
>>> y = copy.deepcopy(x)
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
True
>>> isinstance(x(), y)
True
```

It doesn't matter if there are N objects of type `type`, given an object, only one will be its class, hence it's safe to compare for reference in this case. And since reference comparison will always be cheaper than value comparison, I wanted to know whether or not my assertion above holds. I'm reaching the conclusion that it does, unless someone presents evidence in contrary.

Comment: If you want to know which is fastest for your use, just test it with the timeit module.

Comment: Classes are not singletons - they are instances of their metaclasses - the default metaclass is "type", whcihin a normal Python porgram will have lots of instances.

Comment: @jsbueno That's not what I meant. Of course there are many instances, but only one will be "the class" of a given object, right? In other words if `x.__class__ == a` and `a == b` then `a is b` (for well behaved `__eq__`, of course), that's the conjecture I'm trying to confirm/refute.

Comment: `a is b` has nothing to do with `__eq__` on the objects `a`, `b`.  it checks `id(a) == id(b)` no more no less.  jsbueno is saying that since the `x.__class__`, whatever it is, is not a singleton so there is no guarantee that there won't be more of them floating around - hence don't use `is`.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your feedback, I think all answers (and comments) added something useful to the discussion. I can only choose one as the "accepted" though, so I'm picking what I felt was the more accurate.

Comment: The title is a DoS attack on my brain's syntax unit :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between type(obj) and obj.\_\_class\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class)

Comment: @AloisMahdal That is why I think Python is way too complex than C++

Comment: @Deqing that's a logical fallacy: the title is in English mixed with Python, so the property of the title [being ddos on my brain] does not say anything about complexity of Python; it only speaks about this particular instance of mixing the two (being amplified by the fact that Python *uses* words of common EN as `is`, and the effect of absence of tick marks). (I do like the title as is --- my comment was just a joke).

Comment: @mgibsonbr  `if x.__class__ == a and a == b then a is b` see here -> [Are classobjects singleton in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33924950/674039)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For old-style classes, there is a difference:

```
>>> class X: pass
... 
>>> type(X)
<type 'classobj'>
>>> X.__class__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: class X has no attribute '__class__'
>>> x = X()
>>> x.__class__
<class __main__.X at 0x171b5d50>
>>> type(x)
<type 'instance'>
```

The point of new-style classes was to unify class and type. Technically speaking, `__class__` is the only solution that will work both for new and old-style class instances, but it will also throw an exception on old-style class objects themselves. You can call `type()` on any object, but not every object has `__class__`. Also, you can muck with `__class__` in a way you can't muck with `type()`.

```
>>> class Z(object):
...     def __getattribute__(self, name):
...             return "ham"
... 
>>> z = Z()
>>> z.__class__
'ham'
>>> type(z)
<class '__main__.Z'>
```

Personally, I usually have an environment with new-style classes only, and as a matter of style prefer to use `type()` as I generally prefer built-in functions when they exist to using magic attributes. For example, I would also prefer `bool(x)` to `x.__nonzero__()`.

Comment: That would make `__class__` preferable then, right? Since it will work both for new and old style classes.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to answer this question as well as I can. I don't think there is a universal answer, but if you can be sure you won't need to use this on old-style classes, `type()` should work better.

Comment: One weird quirk is that even in Python 3, `.__class__` is still used by `isinstance` checks, which is something that is used deliberately by proxy objects (such as the ones provided by [the `wrapt` library](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt)). So it actually turns out that if when proxy objects are in play, `foo.__class__` is more "correct" than `type(foo)` unless you're actively looking to specially handle, reject, or break proxy objects within your code.

Comment: Needing to use `type()` or `.__class__` is pretty rare these days. I mainly use them during debugging, for which I would absolutely want to know if some sort of proxy class were involved. I wouldn't want to make assumptions about what behavior is desired as a universal.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman Right, hence the "unless". Anyway, I actually find a lot of use nowadays for either `type(self)` or `self.__class__`: to get `__name__` in the `__repr__` implementations of my classes and to construct new instances of the current class (f.e. in `__add__`), it's nicer for subclassing, especially the `__repr__` case (where a hard-coded class name is automatically wrong in the majority of cases where the rest of the repr might be perfectly fine still). (In which case the difference only comes up if code calls the unbound method with a wrapped instance as the first argument.)

Comment: Oh, it's actually more painfully complicated/inconsistent than I thought: `type(obj)` *is* overwritten by setting `obj.__class__` but it is *not* middlemanned by `__getattribute__` nor by a `@property` named `__class__`. (A maximally transparent proxy object therefore can make the tradeoff of using the former method to behave exactly like the wrapped object to `type` calls, or using one of the latter two methods to not break objects which change their `.__class__` dynamically.) Meanwhile, `isinstance` is overridden by any of those three methods.

Comment: Another possibly relevant criteria for deciding when to do `type()` vs `.__class__` is that certain other language features use the `type` behavior - for example, overriding `.__class__` on an instance *will* cause `with` to use `.__enter__` and `.__exit__` methods from the override, but `with` will ignore `@property` and `__getattribute__` middlemanning of `__class__`, so `type` would be the more "correct" choice if we were building something like `contextlib.ExitStack`, unless you're actively looking to behave differently than the language behaves.

Answer (score 17):

The result of `type()` is equivalent to `obj.__class__` in new style classes, and class objects are not safe for comparison using `is`, use `==` instead.

**For new style classes** the preferable way here would be `type(obj) == Foo`.

As Michael Hoffman pointed out in his answer, there is a difference here between new and old style classes, so for backwards compatible code you may need to use `obj.__class__ == Foo`.

For those claiming that `isinstance(obj, Foo)` is preferable, consider the following scenario:

```
class Foo(object):
    pass

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

>>> obj = Bar()
>>> isinstance(obj, Foo)
True
>>> type(obj) == Foo
False
```

The OP wants the behavior of `type(obj) == Foo`, where it will be false even though `Foo` is a base class of `Bar`.

Comment: Can you give an example of a class object that is equal but not identical?

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: If you use a metaclass, could you override the `__eq__` method for the class itself? I can't see any use for it, but it's the only exception I can think of.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman - I can't, but this is a value comparison and there are no guarantees that equivalent values will have the same identity.  It is an implementation detail when that is the case, and even though there are some instances (this may be one of them) where the implementation makes it impossible to have equal and non-identical values, that doesn't make it safe.

Comment: @F.J Yeah, that's exactly my point. Python's [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says that "Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with 'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators." Well, a class object is like a singleton in the sense that another class will never be "the" class of an object... or at least my common sense says so. However, I'd like to find references to confirm (or refute) that.

Comment: "The result of type() is equivalent to obj.__class__ in new style classes" is a reasonable assumption about sane code but it is not guaranteed by Python.  If the class body definition includes `__class__ = 123` then the builtin `type` returns the correct result (that is, it returns the object that effectively controls the behavior).  One could also probably do nasty things with `getattribute`.

Comment: In my experience, making a transparent dict proxy with a hook in `__getitem__` required setting `__class__` to something different to type.  This is because there are fast-paths in CPython source code that would bypass the `__getitem__` hook on certain actions (updating another dict with the contents of the dict proxy, for example) if the proxy directly inherited from dict, but we still need it to pass `isinstance` checks.  Just thought y'all might like an example :)

Comment: I'm not sure about guarantees in the actual language spec, but in CPython the class will be a singleton unless it's imported a second time from a different location (something to avoid all the time).  But in that case, I'm not at all convinced they would pass equality checks either (does anyone know for sure?).

Comment: The obj.__class__ can be overridden by way of @property decorator.

Comment: How can you be sure that "== should be preferred to is" when you can't imagine a scenario where they'd behave differently? It seems like you're assuming that in any of the hypothetical scenarios where they'd behave differently, the programmer would prefer to test for equality than identity - whether this is true would surely depend on the meaning of '==' and what the programmer is trying to do... Maybe you are more interested in the symbolic nature of the type rather than whatever '==' could mean apart from 'is'...

Comment: The first paragraph of this answer is totally wrong.

Answer (score 15):

`is` should only be used for identity checks, not type checks (there is an exception to the rule where you can and should use `is` for check against singletons).

Note: I would generally not use `type` and `==` for type checks, either.  The preferable way for type checks is `isinstance(obj, Foo)`.  If you ever have a reason to check if something is not an subclass instance, it smells like a fishy design to me.  When `class Bar(Foo):`, then `Bar` **is a** `Foo`, and you should be avoiding any situations where some part of your code has to work on a `Foo` instance but breaks on a `Bar` instance.

Comment: Right. If you can't do that, you usually have a broken design.

Comment: BTW I agree my design is not the best one, but I'm writing a few very specialized classes that need to be optimized for space, and are not meant to be subclassed outside my library. That's not something I'd do in the general case though...

Comment: If you're optimizing for space, consider using [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Proceed with caution! :)

Comment: @jathanism Thanks a lot, didn't even imagine something like that existed in Python! Doesn't solve all my problems, but for most of them it's better than the alternatives I knew of.

Comment: I use isinstance 99% of the time in my code, but there are a few places where I use type(x) where acting on a subclass would not work.  For instance, say I have a slotted class that I know has only two attributes that can only be simple objects, but that gets copied a lot, I can save a lot of time in copying overriding `__deepcopy__` to simply create a new object with those two attributes (faster than copy.py's code) and then resort to the copy.py code if it's a subclass.  Then subclassing classes do not need to know to override `__deepcopy__` itself.

Answer (score -3):

> Update: Thanks all for the feedback. I'm still puzzled by whether or not class objects are singletons, my common sense says they are, but it's been really hard to get a confirmation (try googling for "python", "class" and "unique" or "singleton").

I can confirm that `__instance__` is a singleton. Here is the proof.

```
>>> t1=File.test()
made class
>>> t2=File.test()
made class
>>> print t1.__class__()
made class
<File.test object at 0x1101bdd10>
>>> print t2.__class__()
made class
<File.test object at 0x1101bdd10>
```

As you can see both `t1` and `t2` print out the same value in memory even though `t1` and `t2` are at different values in memory. Here is the proof of that.

```
>>> print t1
<File.test object at 0x1101bdc90>
>>> print t2
<File.test object at 0x1101bdcd0>
```

The `__instance__` method only exists if you used `class "name"(object):`. If you use the classic style class, `class "name":`, than the `__instance__` method doesn't exist.

What this means is to be the most generic you probably want to use `type` unless you know for a fact instance does exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! About the last comment, just paste the whole code, then select it and click the "code sample" button (or simply indent your code by 4 spaces before pasting here, whichever is easier).

Comment: This is not "proof", it's just one example.  Here's another `x, y = 7, 7; x is y` will evaluate True but it is not proof that integers are singletons (they are not).

Comment: What exactly is "`__instance__`"?

Comment: Worth noting: while integers in general aren't singletons (this is dead obvious because: there is more than one of them), in cpython 7 is indeed a singleton, as are "small" strings and other small integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924950/are-classobjects-singletons