# Does type(a_subclass) return a singleton in Python?

Tags: python, equality

I'm new to Python, and I need to compare two responses to `type(a_subclass)` for equality (*i.e.*, I need to be sure the two subclasses of a parent class are exactly the same.) Can I safely assume that `type` returns singletons and use the `is` operator? Or is `==` necessary? Is there something else I should be worried about, like comparing package and module names?

Note the [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924950/are-classobjects-singletons), to which the answers are confusing at best. I'm kinda looking for a 'yes' or a 'no.'

Comment: Related, but possibly outdated: [Python `type()` or `__class__`, `==` or `is`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9610993/11082165)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are classobjects singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924950/are-classobjects-singletons)

Comment: [user2357112 supports Monica's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33926750/11082165) in the proposed duplicate talks about CPython 3.5, but it also applies to [CPython 3.10](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Objects/typeobject.c#L4338) and probably all versions in between. `type` objects still use the default equality comparison from `object`, which is a pointer comparison and therefore equivalent to using `is`.

Comment: This article is a bit off-topic, but provided an easy-to-read explanation of Python's type object that would probably be useful to someone who had this same question: https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t use the word “singleton” for type objects (in this question or the near-duplicate): a singleton is the only object of its *type*, and `type(1)` and `type(None)` are two objects of the same type (namely, `type`).  The proper way to phrase this question would seem to be “Can two `type` **objects** represent the same type?”.

If so, it might be reasonable for them to compare `==`, as suggested in the question.  (Conversely, one could imagine *different* types comparing `==` based on something like their sizes or names, but we can ignore such useless possibilities.)  However, types are **mutable** in Python, the simplest example being that you can assign static variables as `Class.var=2`.  Plainly it must be possible to read that value with `type(Class()).var`, which implies that they are the **same** object.  While it would be *possible* to implement such syntax through a proxy object, it is correct to assume that no such needless complexity is introduced (especially as it would involve additional memory allocation and reference counting overhead).

Seen from this perspective, the answer is almost a tautology: Python types are defined by the **identity** of their representative objects, so of course the same object must be used everywhere.

Comment: I love the way you build this answer up, almost like a formal proof.  But I don't think "it is correct to assume that no such needless complexity is introduced", you can never assume anything.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I mean that the assumption turns out to be correct (as it should be, since the alternative would be significantly less efficient).

Comment: You could also assume that dictionaries are iterated in a random order, because the alternative would be less efficient.  Except it turned out the alternative wasn't, and now dictionaries are iterated in the order of insertion and that is guaranteed by the language specification.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Obviously not all “reasonable” assumptions are borne out.  It’s pretty hard to get better, though, than “store a pointer directly to the type object and return it on request”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavisHerring! It's very informative, and points to a flaw in my thinking about Python, namely that things like class instances are 'stamped out' from a single defined class object that's immutable (as in java or .net.) and that can be used as the basis of comparison along these lines.