# How to retrieve the names of children classes in the inherited one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have a base class which I inherit from when creating other classes.

One of the things I would like to do is, at `__init__()` time, to log the parent class the object is instantied from. Today I do it the explicit way:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, src):
        print(f"hello from {src}")

class One(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("one")

class Two(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("two")

One()
Two()
```

This outputs

```
hello from one
hello from two
```

**Is there a way for `Main` to know which class ultimately instantiated the object?**

I am thinking of something along the lines of (this is just a wildly hand-waving example, to show what that I would like to call bare a bare `__init__` instead of also passing a descriptive parameter as in the code above)

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self, src):
        wherefrom = something_which_holds_the_class_hierarchy[1].__name__ # index 1 = one class above this one
        print(f"hello from {wherefrom}")

class One(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Two(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

One()
Two()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for messing with [MRO](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path)s for this, just look at `type(self)`:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f"Hello from {type(self).__name__}!")

class Sub(Main):
    pass

class SubSub(Sub):
    pass

Main()
Sub()
SubSub()
```

results in:

```
Hello from Main!
Hello from Sub!
Hello from SubSub!
```

`self.__class__` [is equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611031/5951320) `type(self)`, you can use either.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f"hello from {self.__class__}")
```

Answer (score 0):

use inspect.getmro function

```
import inspect
inspect.getmro(Two)
```