# See if type meta object is an instance of another class

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm wondering if there's a way of seeing whether a class is inherited from another class based on the `type` object for a given object.

Say I have the class `MyList` as defined below:

```py
class MyList(list):
    pass
```

Now consider the following:

```py
>>> my_list = MyList()
>>> type(my_list).__name__
'MyList'
>>> isinstance(my_list, list)
True  # as expected
>>> isinstance(type(my_list), list)
False  # how can I get this to be True?
```

So my questions are:

1. What is a pythonic way of seeing whether the type object for a class is an instance of (inherited from) another class?
2. Can you retrieve the class of an object based on the `type` metaclass instance for it? I would imagine this as something like `type(my_list).class`

Comment: Is `issubclass()` what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! After a few preliminary tests, that seems to be doing the trick. Thank you so much @sj95126!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely as a [pro-forma action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294791/what-if-i-answer-a-question-in-a-comment) ...

The solution is to use `issubclass()`:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     pass
...
>>> my_list = MyList()
>>> issubclass(MyList, list)
True
>>> issubclass(my_list.__class__, list)
True
```

Comment: This is great thank you! Would is also possibly be slightly more pythonic to say `type(my_list)` instead of `my_list.__class__`?

Comment: @EthanPosner: There's a question about that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610993/python-type-or-class-or-is)