# Why is it considered bad practice to hardcode the name of a class inside that class's methods?

Tags: python, oop

In python, why is it a bad thing to do something like this:

```
class Circle:
  pi = 3.14159 # class variable
  def __init__(self, r = 1):
    self.radius = r
  def area(self):
    return Circle.pi * squared(self.radius)

def squared(base): return pow(base, 2)
```

The area method could be defined as follows:

```
def area(self): return self.__class__.pi * squared(self.radius)
```

which is, unless I'm very much mistaken, considered a better way to reference a class variable. The question is why? Intuitively, I don't like it but I don't seem to completely understand this.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10386166/1079354

Comment: there is no self in area
def area(self):

Comment: You misunderstood something, you should use `Cirlce.pi`, not `self.__class__.pi` or `type(self).pi`.

Comment: @Versatile seems like i made a typo, there must be self in area.

Comment: @BiRico Why shouldn't I use self.__class__.pi?

Comment: Where are you getting this premise that it's bad practice to refer to the class name directly?

Comment: Ask yourself is "pi" an attribute of 1) the specific circle, 2) the "class" of Circle, or 3) of all Circles. In reality "pi" is a universal constant, so why not use a module level variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it considered bad practice to hardcode the name of a class inside that class's methods?

**It's not.** I don't know why you think it is.

There are plenty of good reasons to hardcode the name of a class inside its methods. For example, using `super` on Python 2:

```
super(ClassName, self).whatever()
```

People often try to replace this with `super(self.__class__, self).whatever()`, and they are **dead wrong** to do so. The first argument **must** be the actual class the `super` call occurs in, not `self.__class__`, or the lookup will find the wrong method.

Another reason to hardcode the class name is to avoid overrides. For example, say you've implemented one method using another, as follows:

```
class Foo(object):
    def big_complicated_calculation(self):
        return # some horrible mess
    def slightly_different_calculation(self):
        return self.big_complicated_calculation() + 2
```

If you want `slightly_different_calculation` to be independent of overrides of `big_complicated_calculation`, you can explicitly refer to `Foo.big_complicated_calculation`:

```
def slightly_different_calculation(self):
    return Foo.big_complicated_calculation(self) + 2
```

Even when you *do* want to pick up overrides, it's usually better to change `ClassName.whatever` to `self.whatever` instead of `self.__class__.whatever`.

Answer (score 4):

Because in case you subclass the class it will no longer refer to the class, but its parent. In your case it really doesn't make a difference, but in many cases it does:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    name = "Rectangle"
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.__class__.name) # or print(type(self).name)

class Square(Rectangle):
    name = "Square"
```

If you instantiate `Square` and then call its `print_name` method, it'll print "Square". If you'd use `Rectangle.name` instead of `self.__class__.name` (or `type(self).name`), it'd print "Rectangle".

Comment: It should also be noted that as long as you keep a clear distinction between instance attributes and class attributes, you don't even _need_ to get a reference to the class.  `self.name` will resolve to the same thing that `type(self).name` resolves to as long as you haven't set a `name` on `self`.

Comment: This is assuming you want the thing to be overrideable, and if you want it to be overrideable, it's probably better to use `self.whatever` instead of `self.__class__.whatever`. Not everything should actually be overrideable.

Answer (score 2):

I can name here two reasons

Inheritance

```
class WeirdCircle(Circle):
    pi = 4

c = WeirdCircle()
print(c.area()) 
# returning 4 with self.__class__.pi 
# and 3.14159 with Circle.pi
```

When you want to rename the class, there is only one spot to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Zen of python says keep your code as simple as possible to make it readable. Why to get into using the class name or super. If you just use self then it will refer the relevant class and print its relevant variable. Refer below code.

```
class Rectangle(object):
    self.name = "Rectangle"
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class Square(Rectangle):
    name = 'square'

sq = Square()
sq.print_name
```