# How to access name of named tuple in Typescript

Tags: typescript, namedtuple, keyof, nameof

I want to access the name from a named tuple to use within one of my functions. Is there a way to access the name only, similar to how you can access the type only by using the index of the tuple element.

```
type NamedThing = [emailId: string, anotherField: number]

// like you access the type here
type TypeOfFirst = NamedThing['0']

// how can I access the name here
const NameOfFirst = NamedThing['0']['__name__'] // Error on the __name__ accessor
```

I understand that this can be done in python using the way I described above. Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10939786/18620006) that shows that. How can I do this in Typescript?

Comment: you cannot do that in TS. `NamedThing['0']['__name__']` means there is an Array of objects `NamedThing` where get the first item `[0]` and get the value of the property `__name__` that exists in the first object. And that is JS, not TS. TS here does not works as python/java or any other language, because the named tuple is only a representation for you (the developer). It's NOT part of the actual JS runtime

Comment: Moreover `[emailId: string, anotherField: number]` states the first item of the array should be string and the second to be number. And thats it. The context dies there itself. So there is no magic `__name__` or equivalent that exists, which would get you what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript exists to generate Javascript runtime after all. For this reason, some things are not possible if Javascript itself does not support it.

If you were to compile following code:

```typescript
type NamedThing = [
    emailId: string, anotherField: number
]

type NamedThing2 = {
    emailId: string; anotherField: number;
}

export const nTuple:NamedThing = ["email", 123]
export const nStruct:NamedThing2 = { emailId : "email", anotherField : 123 }
```

It becomes:

```javascript
exports.nTuple = ["email", 123];
exports.nStruct = { emailId: "email", anotherField: 123 };
```

Notice there is no way of knowing `emailId` and `anotherField` from nTuple. Because Javascript has no named tuple in the first place. No actual data type is translated into js.

If you were to implement named tuple similar to that from Python, you have to do it manually, such as:

```typescript
function toTuple(obj:{[name:string]:any}) {
    return Object
        .keys(obj)
        .map(key=>obj[key])
}

function getByIndex(obj:{[name:string]:any}, index:number) {
    const key = Object
        .keys(obj)[index]

    return obj[key]
}

const nStruct = { emailId : "email", anotherField : 123 } // not actually named tuple.

const email = nStruct["emailId"] // as if it's named tuple.
const aField = getByIndex(nStruct, 1) // as if it's named tuple.
const actualTuple = toTuple(nStruct) // ["email",  123]
```

Comment: Couldn't TypeScript translate the key accesses into index accesses, since tuples are fixed and ordered? i.e `nTuple["emailId"]` would compile to `nTuple[0]`, since TS can see that `emailId` is the first named value.