# What is the purpose of checking self.__class__?

Tags: python, class, oop, interface, self

What is the purpose of checking `self.__class__` ? I've found some code that creates an abstract interface class and then checks whether its `self.__class__` is itself, e.g.

```
class abstract1 (object):
  def __init__(self):
    if self.__class__ == abstract1: 
      raise NotImplementedError("Interfaces can't be instantiated")
```

**What is the purpose of that?
Is it to check whether the class is a type of itself?**

The code is from NLTK's http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability-pysrc.html#ProbDistI

Comment: I think this requires more context.  Where did you "find" this code?  It's basically broken.

Comment: @Iguananaut: Why is it broken? It works *fine* when used as intended; as an abstract base class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure earlier it was something different?  I don't know--I agree, what's on there now is not broken.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`self.__class__` is a reference to the *type* of the current instance.

For instances of `abstract1`, that'd be the `abstract1` class *itself*, which is what you don't want with an abstract class. Abstract classes are only meant to be subclassed, not to create instances directly:

```
>>> abstract1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __init__
NotImplementedError: Interfaces can't be instantiated
```

For an instance of a *subclass* of `abstract1`, `self.__class__` would be a reference to the specific subclass:

```
>>> class Foo(abstract1): pass
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.__class__
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> f.__class__ is Foo
True
```

Throwing an exception here is like using an `assert` statement elsewhere in your code, it protects you from making silly mistakes.

Note that the *pythonic* way to test for the type of an instance is to use the [`type()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) instead, together with an *identity* test with the `is` operator:

```
class abstract1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if type(self) is abstract1: 
            raise NotImplementedError("Interfaces can't be instantiated")
```

`type()` should be preferred over `self.__class__` because the latter [can be shadowed by a class attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10633356/100297).

There is little point in using an equality test here as for custom classes, `__eq__` is basically implemented as an identity test anyway.

Python also includes a standard library to define abstract base classes, called [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). It lets you mark methods and properties as abstract and will refuse to create instances of any subclass that has not yet re-defined those names.

Comment: Because everything in python is an object, a type is also an object. So a normal object's `__class__` points to the type **object** of its class. And the type object's `__class__` points to the meta class **object**.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you posted there is a no-op; `self.__class__ == c1` is not part of a conditional so the boolean is evaluated but nothing is done with the result.

You could try to make an abstract base class that checks to see if `self.__class__` is equal to the abstract class as opposed to a hypothetical child (via an if statement), in order to prevent the instantiation of the abstract base class itself due to developer mistake.

Comment: Although for more recent versions of Python one should just use an abstract base class using `abc.ABCMeta`.

Comment: An ABC can still be instantiated directly.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of that? Is it to check whether the class is a type of itself?

Yes, if you try to construct an object of type `Abstract1` it'll throw that exception telling you that you're not allowed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3 either using `type()` to check for the type or `__class__` will return the same result.

```
class C:pass
ci=C()
print(type(ci)) #<class '__main__.C'>
print(ci.__class__) #<class '__main__.C'>
```

---

I recently checked the [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/dataclasses.py) for the `@dataclass` decorator (Raymond Hettinger is directly involved into that project), and they are using `__class__` to refer to the type.

So it is not wrong to use `__class__` :)

Answer (score 0):

The clues are in the name of the class, "abstract1", and in the error. This is intended to be an abstract class, meaning one that is intended to be subclassed. Each subclass will provide its own behaviour. The abstract class itself serves to document the interface, i.e. the methods and arguments that classes implementing the interface are expected to have. It is not meant to be instantiated itself, and the test is used to tell whether we are in the class itself or a subclass.

See the section on Abstract Classes in this [article](http://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods) by Julien Danjou.

Answer (score 0):

This is useful for **immutable** static fields. Without `.__class__.` it's a different varaible. No need to use `@classmethod`.

```py
class NoClass:
    bo: bool = False

    def makeTrue(self):
        self.bo = True

no_class = NoClass()
print(f"before: {NoClass.bo=}")  # before: NoClass.bo=False
no_class.makeTrue()
print(f"after:  {NoClass.bo=}")  # after:  NoClass.bo=False


class WithClass:
    bo: bool = False

    def makeTrue(self):
        self.__class__.bo = True


with_class = WithClass()
print(f"before: {WithClass.bo=}")  # before: WithClass.bo=False
with_class.makeTrue()
print(f"after:  {WithClass.bo=}")  # after:  WithClass.bo=True
```