# Pdb Meaning of '_example_'

Tags: python, pdb

New to pdb and I am using p dir(a) to list all of the attributes of object a in my Django App. But I don't understand what the attributes such as `'_class_', '_dict_'` etc mean.

Comment: They are internally used methods. They are sometimes referred to as "dunder" methods, because they have a Double UNDERscore in front and behind them `__something__`

Comment: Did you try searching for them?

Answer (score 0):

These attributes have nothing to do with pdb, actually. They are built-in attributes of Python objects. For example, the `__dict__` attribute is a dictionary of all the attributes the instance of a class has. You can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877290/what-is-the-dict-dict-attribute-of-a-python-class). As for `__class__`, this is a reference to the class the instance has been spawned from. Again, a more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599375/what-is-the-purpose-of-checking-self-class-python).