# How do I compare the type of two variables without generating PyLint warnings?

Tags: python

Say I have two variables:

```
a = 123
b = 234
```

I want to compare their type. Clearly the obvious way is:

```
type(a) == type(b)
```

However, pylint gives me a warning, which I would like to avoid if possible:

```
Using type() instead of isinstance() for a typecheck. (unidiomatic-typecheck)
```

(I believe this isn't specifically warning about my use.)

In the case of comparing *two* variable types, isinstance can't be used, I believe.

How do I compare the type of two variables without generating PyLint warnings?

Comment: Why are you comparing the types?  PyLint is warning you that comparing types may not be what you really want to do.

Comment: Does `isinstance(a, type(b))` get rid of the warning?

Comment: Comparing that two objects are the same type is not something commonly done in python. Why do you feel like you want to do that?

Comment: @BrenBarn I want to know if two dict entries have the same type so I can merge the values.

Comment: @AFunderburg Yes it does.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? What kinds of values are you expecting? In your example, you give integers. What does it mean to merge two integers? The comments by BrenBarn and Chad S. are asking you to take a step back. You might be missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: @AdamFunderburg While `isinstance(a,type(b)) and isinstance(b, type(a))` would be equivalent to a type comparison, it's also a whole lot slower.

Comment: Complemeting @AdamFunderburg answer with a possible gotcha. For reasons, bools are instances of ints
 
```
>>> x = False
>>> print(type(x))
<class 'bool'>
>>> isinstance(x, int)
True
```

Answer (score 4):

Just turn off the pylint warning.

On a single line, you can do that thusly:

```
types_match = type(a) is type(b) # pylint: disable=unidiomatic-typecheck
```

See https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html

Answer (score 2):

People get too hung up about linters. It's like the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). They are guidelines, and you have to use your own judgment.

If you *need* to know whether the type of something is the same as the type of something else, then absolutely the straightforward

```
type(a) == type(b)
```

is the most Pythonic way. It's **not** idiomatic Python to jump through crazy hoops to do simple things if you can avoid it.

All that said, it is usually not the case in Python that you really need to know whether the types of two things are exactly the same. (See comments by BrenBarn and Chad S.) So the linter may be pointing to a larger "code smell" than just that one line which compares the two types.

Comment: Yes.  The point is not that `type(a) == type(b)` is an unidiomatic way to decide if two objects are the same type.  The point is that deciding if two objects are the same type is not usually an idiomatic thing to do at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you *absolutely must* compare if two of anything are of the [*exact*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34639306/1558430) same type, and you cannot use `type()` for some reason, [the last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060547/1558430) may be:

```
a.__class__ is b.__class__
```

Note also the limitation of this check on old-style classes.