# Is it bad practice to access a class variable through 'self'?

Tags: python, class, instance, self

Doing so suits my needs but I wonder if it's considered blasphemous (or, even, un-pythonic).

**Example:**

```
class A:
    _class_specific = 1

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.instance_specific = i
        
    def get_special_sum(self):
        return self._class_specific + self.instance_specific

t = A(2)
t.get_special_sum()  #< Returns 3
```

**Reason for doing so:**

I have a class variable `_ID` and an instance method `check(self)` defined in a Base class. Child classes have their own values for `_ID`. The inherited `check(self)` method must have access to instance-specific variables as well as the `_ID` variable of a given genus, which it will access through `self._ID`

Although the above works perfectly I wonder if there is a more explicit way of doing it? ...other than leaving a glaringly obvious comment making clear what the intention is...

Comment: `self.__class__._class_specific + self.instance_specific` would more explicit.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Great, thanks! But it's a little ugly. I was thinking `type(self)._ID` could do the trick. But I kind of like how Python just goes up a level in scope if no instance variable is found. I just don't know whether it's good practice.

Comment: I don't think it is bad practice at all. That's what the namespace fallbacking is for. `self.__class__` and `type(self)` are equivalent. I consider the first more explicit, but this and their aesthetics are, of course, a matter of taste.

Comment: Dunder attributes should generally not be used directly; they serve as implementation details for various protocols.

Comment: Beside the point, but I just edited and removed "the `self` keyword" because it's not a keyword, it's just convention. But that's not relevant to the question.

Comment: This is totally normal. Tye alternative is to specifically use the class, but that has different semantics if inheritance is involved, so whichever one you want

Comment: @user2390182 `self.__class__` and `type(self)` are not equivalent, but you'll rarely see it. For example, [`weakref.proxy` can "lie" via `__class__`](/a/73348651/4518341), so which one you use depends what you want to check for exactly.

Comment: @pfabri It might be "bad practice" setting off someone's alarm bell of like, "this isn't answerable because it's opinion-based". You might consider clarifying the title with something like "... Or is there a more explicit way?"

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no problem  -
And it even adds flexibility to your project: say, you want one specific instance of your class to have a different value for that variable, all you have to do is set it on the instance. Just add some unit tests to ensure everywhere it is used it is being read from `self.`, and there is no drawback.

And, yes (following some of the comments on the O.P.), if you prefer to be explicit about only allowing the value to be fectched from the class, and never be set on the instance, you can do `self.__class__.attribute` or `type(self).attribute`: it is mostly a matter of taste. If `self.__class__` is to be used more than once inside a method, consider assigning it to a variable in the beggining of the method: you can a lot of legibility (and even some micro  optimizations): `cls = self.__class__`

That said, I had used the pattern of reading class values from `self` and using some instances with specific values, and it really feels natural, and "the right way to do it". Just take care when *setting* the attribute instead: `self.attr = X` will always set the attribute in a single instance. When setting you have to be explicit about setting it on the class!

Answer (score 1):

"Bad practice" is subjective, but one thing's for sure, you can more explicitly access a class variable via `type(self)` or `self.__class__`, for example:

```
    def get_special_sum(self):
        return type(self)._class_specific + self.instance_specific
```

So you might prefer to lookup on `self` in cases where the variable *might* be defined on the instance, otherwise it's defined on the class. Maybe that's even the case you've described — you'd be the best judge of that.

As for `type(self)` vs `self.__class__`, see [Difference between type(obj) and obj.__class__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060499/4518341)