# Difference between `isinstance(x, y)` and `x.__class__ == y`

Tags: python

I am familiar with the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class/10633356) between `type(x)` and `x.__class__` but couldn't find an answer to the question if there is any difference between these two ways of checking whether `x` is, say, a dictionary:

```
isinstance(x, dict)

x.__class__ == dict
```

So far, in my experience, the two can be used interchangeably but I would like to know whether there are cases where the results differ, giving rise to a preference for one of both.

**Edit:** alaniwi gave the accepted answer that `isinstance()` also returns True if the object is an instance of a subclass of the class tested against.

Comment: Try it with a defaultdict.

Comment: Or a `Counter`.

Comment: More generally, `isinstance(obj, cls)` will return `True` if `obj` is an instance of a subclass of `cls` (as alternative to `cls` itself).