# Calling __new__ on an Any

Tags: python, deep-copy, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774013/5986907) for custom deepcopy, but with type hints, and mypy's not happy with the `Any` type that I'm using from a third party library. Here's the smallest bit of code I can get to fail

```
# I'm actually using tensorflow.Module, not Any,
# but afaik that's the same thing. See context below
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Any)

def foo(x: T) -> None:
    cls = type(x)
    cls.__new__(cls)
```

I see

```
 error: No overload variant of "__new__" of "type" matches argument type "Type[Any]"
 note: Possible overload variants:
 note:     def __new__(cls, cls: Type[type], o: object) -> type
 note:     def __new__(cls, cls: Type[type], name: str, bases: Tuple[type, ...], namespace: Dict[str, Any]) -> type
```

It passes if I bound `T` to something typed, like `int`, `str` or a custom class. I'm confused about this, cos neither of these overloads matches the [`__new__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). My knowledge of `__new__` is fairly basic.

I'm after either a fix, or if it's a limitation/bug in mypy, an explanation of what that is.

**Context**

The actual function is

```
import tensorflow as tf

T = TypeVar("T", bound=tf.Module)  # tf.Module is untyped

def my_copy(x: T, memo: Dict[int, object]) -> T:
    do_something_with_a_tf_module(x)

    cls = type(x)
    new = cls.__new__(cls)
    memo[id(self)] = new

    for name, value in x.__dict__.items():
        setattr(new, name, copy.deepcopy(value, memo))

    return new
```

curiously, If I instead make this a method

```
class Mixin(tf.Module):
    def __deepcopy__(self: T, memo: Dict[int, object]) -> T:
        ...  # the same implementation as `my_copy` above
```

there's no error

Comment: The signatures are those of calling ``type``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sorry i don't understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: `mypy` doesn't know that you assigned a value of type `int` to `x`, only that `x` could be *any* type. As such, it doesn't know what type of either `cls` or `cls.__new__` , and thus it can't tell if `cls` is a valid argument for `cls.__new__`.

Comment: @chepner that suggests to me that it's not reliable to call `cls.__new__(cls)` on any old result of `type(...)`, because the signature of `__new__` depends on the class. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure I would characterize the code as unreliable, rather just something that inherently relies on dynamic typing. Not all valid Python code can be statically typed. Note that `mypy` is (trivially) happy with the code if you simply don't annotate `x`.

Comment: Looking at this code again, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve anyway. Even for the types that do support ``cls.__new__(cls)`` (which are not all!) many will not support the ``self.__dict__`` and ``setattr(self, ...)``. Case in point, this cannot work for ``x: Any = 1`` – an integer has neither a dict nor would it support item assignment.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ok. In my actual use case, `x` is an instance of a specific custom class (or subclass thereof), that's typed to `Any` due to lack of third party type hints. I'll update the question

Comment: Why don't you typehint ``x: Foo`` then, or even rely on ``x`` being inferred? ``Any`` will bring no advantage for type safety (it literally has no type information).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi this is a simplified version. In the real thing, `x` is a parameter typed with `TypeVar("T", Foo)`, which I have assumed means it's essentially `Any` given `Foo` is untyped. I'll add the context in a bit

Comment: Not sure how to relate the old and new parts – ``x`` (I assume it should be ``self`` actually) is already annotated via the signature. What you should annotate is ``new`` as ``new: T = cls.__new__(cls)``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `x` should be `self` yes - copy paste error. the error remains if I annotate `new`

Comment: How so? New is the only thing inferred to be Any. Do you still have an annotation for something else? It might be sensible to [edit] your question again so that there is only a single code block with well-defined issue.

Comment: Sorry, it is getting increasingly difficult to work out what you are actually asking. Please [edit] your question to *reduce* the several different cases to one single, focused question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi the confusion is probably cos I didn't use a function. I've used that instead

Answer (score 5):

The __ new __ suggestions you're getting from mypy are for the type class itself.  You can see the constructors match perfectly:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

```
class type(object)
class type(name, bases, dict)
```

The complaint by mypy technically makes sense, because you're calling __ new __ from an object returned by type().  If we get the __ class __ of such an object (such as cls), we'll get <class 'type'>:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> type(x)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(x).__class__
<class 'type'>
```

This might be what's tripping up mypy when T is unbounded (i.e. not specified at compile time).  If you were inside a class, as you've noticed, and as mentioned in PEP 484 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#annotating-instance-and-class-methods), it would be possible for mypy to discern the type as being the class of self, which is unambiguous.

With a standalone function, there are three approaches.  One is to silence mypy directly with comment # type:ignore .  The second is to grab __ class __ directly from x instead of using type(x), which generally returns the __ class __ anyway (see link above).  The third is to use the fact that __ new __ is a class method and call it with x itself.

As long you want to use Any, there's no way to clarify to mypy that type(x) is anything other than Type[T`-1]  while maintaining the generic nature (for instance, you *could* notate the `cls = type(x)` line with something like `# type: List[int]`, but that would defeat the purpose), and it seems to be resolving the ambiguity with the return type of the type() command.

This coding works for a list (with a silly, element-wise list copy) and keeps me from getting any mypy errors:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Any, cast
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Any)

def foo(x: T) -> T:
    cls = type(x)
    res = cls.__new__(cls) # type: ignore
    for v in x:
      res.append(v)
    return res

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = foo(x)
y += [5]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively:

```
def foo(x: T) -> T:
    cls = x.__class__
    res = cls.__new__(cls)
    for v in x:
      res.append(v)
    return res
```

Third Approach:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Any
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Any)

def foo(x: T) -> T:
    res = x.__new__(type(x))
    for v in x:
      res.append(v)
    return res

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = foo(x)
y += [5]
print(x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Are you sure that is working, not just suppressing errors? It asserts that the *class* is a T, not its instance.

Comment: Nah. That would for example assert that the list type is a list. It effectively says "is of itself". One casts a value as a type.

Comment: I guess the ``cast(T, cls)`` works because ``__new__`` is a classmethod. So for example ``[].__new__`` and ``list.__new__`` are the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but you're right that it's still technically incorrect to cast a type to the same type.  I just added a note on using the __class__ attribute directly instead of going through type() to get it.

Comment: `.__class__` fixes the error for me, thanks. What I'm surprised by is that `.__class__` and `type` don't do the same thing when called with a single object. And similarly that `type` doesn't have an (overloaded) definition of `type: T -> Type[T]`

Comment: See especially the note on how both old- and new-style classes can have different results (tl;dr you can override the __class__ attribute):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class  (Although in my python 3.8 I'm not seeing the old-style problem demonstrated) This is why I put the ignore recommendation first, because then at least you're still using type().

Comment: There are no old-style classes in Python3. It looks as if MyPy treats ``x.__class__`` and ``type(x)`` differently – the former is inferred, the latter typed. That is, mypy has some leeway in adjusting the type of ``x.__class__`` according to context.

Comment: The good news is that, with either approach, using `reveal_type()` shows that mypy considers `y` to be of type `List[int]`, which means further type checking isn't impeded.  It does still consider `res` to be of type `Any` though.

Comment: I've upvoted and given you the bounty because this is helpful and solves my problem, but I'll leave it as unanswered because I'm still curious why `__class__` works when `type` doesn't