# How to find the real type of an object in Python

Tags: python, pycharm

How to find the real return type of a method in Python?

For example, I want to enable type hinting in Pycharm so that autocompletion works, but it is surprisingly not easy to find the exact object type even while in the debugger, and even after looking at the method bodies.

I expected `type(someObject)` to return something meaningful for objects but for most objects it returns `<type 'instance'>` which is hardly of any use.

For example, how can I find out what is the type of the response object returned by a call to `urllib2.urlopen(url)` so that I can mark the local variable using a [Pycharm type hint](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html#d316912e312) to make autocompletion work?

I realize that everything is dynamic in Python, and that programming to an interface is not a widely used Python paradigm, but at least I would like to know how far can we go in terms of type inference, specifically for comfortable IDE support and 'lazy' programming with autocompletion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does \`type(myField)\` return \`<type 'instance'>\` and not \`<type 'Field'>\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666856/why-does-typemyfield-return-type-instance-and-not-type-field)

Comment: You can't, because multiple `return` statements in the same function may return different types as Python is not statically typed.

Comment: From what I gather from the other question listed as a duplicate it seems that `obj.__class__` should show the correct object class which can be used as a type hint for the IDE. At least it works for the `urllib2.urlopen(url)` which converts to a type hint of `""":type : urllib.addinfourl """` (in Python 2.7) which makes autocompletion work in pycharm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real type of an instance of an old style class is `instance`, regardless it is of any use or not. If you want to know the class it is an instance of you can use `obj.__class__`. But old style classes are not types.

And there's no such a thing like the "return type of a method" in python.

Comment: "regardless it is of any use or not" Well, python devs came up with new style classes for a reason...