# When is type(instance) different from instance.__class__?

Tags: python, class, types

Python has the built-in function [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type):

> *class* `type`(*object*)
>
> With one argument, return the type of an *object*. The return value is a type object and generally the same object as returned by `object.__class__`.

Python also has the special attribute [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__):

> instance.`__class__`
>
> The class to which a class instance belongs.

I used to believe that they both refer to the same object. However in the method [`abc.ABCMeta.__instancecheck__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0/Lib/_py_abc.py#L92-L106) there is a check if they are identical:

```py
    def __instancecheck__(cls, instance):
        """Override for isinstance(instance, cls)."""
        # Inline the cache checking
        subclass = instance.__class__
        # […]
        subtype = type(instance)
        if subtype is subclass:
        # […]
```

When is `type(instance)` different from `instance.__class__`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610993/python-type-or-class-or-is

Comment: @Kasramvd Thanks for that link, I believe it's probably rather a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060499/difference-between-typeobj-and-obj-class. I'm not sure why they haven't showed up when googling the question and neither in the "proposed duplicates" when asking the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type(instance)` and `instance.__class__` may be different, even with [new-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), as Guido van Rossum mentioned in [PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/#the-abc-module-an-abc-support-framework):

> Also, `isinstance(x, B)` is equivalent to `issubclass(x.__class__, B) or issubclass(type(x), B)`. (It is possible `type(x)` and `x.__class__` are not the same object, e.g. when `x` is a proxy object.)

For example, the function [`weakref.proxy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html#weakref.proxy) of the standard library creates proxy objects.

```py
>>> import weakref
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(weakref.proxy(a))
<class 'weakproxy'>
>>> weakref.proxy(a).__class__
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> repr(weakref.proxy(a))
'<weakproxy at 0x10065ab30 to A at 0x1006534c0>'
```

Note that the implementation of the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) method of the proxy object uses `type(instance)`, not `instance.__class__`, since the primary purpose the `__repr__` method is to provide enough information to recreate the object when debugging.

### `type(instance)`

The real class of an `object` instance is stored on the instance in a `__class__` *slot* (i.e. at a fixed offset in the instance layout). It can only be accessed through the [data descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) `vars(object)['__class__']` (whose method `__get__` allows attribute retrieval, whose method `__set__` allows attribute assignment, and whose method `__delete__` forbids attribute deletion), or equivalently through the built-in function `type` (whose one-argument form allows attribute retrieval):

```py
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> vars(object)['__class__'].__get__(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> class B: pass
... 
>>> vars(object)['__class__'].__set__(a, B)
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> vars(object)['__class__'].__get__(a)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> vars(object)['__class__'].__delete__(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't delete __class__ attribute
```

### `instance.__class__`

If the data descriptor `vars(object)['__class__']` is not overridden in an `object` subclass, `instance.__class__` accesses the real class of `instance` through the data descriptor:

```py
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> class B: pass
... 
>>> a.__class__ = B
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> a.__class__
<class '__main__.B'>
>>> del a.__class__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't delete __class__ attribute
```

But if the data descriptor `vars(object)['__class__']` is overridden in an `object` subclass, `instance.__class__` does not access the real class of `instance`. Moreover, if the override is not a data descriptor, it can itself be overridden in `instance`:

```py
>>> class A: __class__ = int  # overrides vars(object)['__class__']
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__
<class 'int'>
>>> a.__class__ = str  # overrides vars(A)['__class__'] (not a data descriptor)
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__
<class 'str'>
>>> del a.__class__
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> a.__class__
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: You can’t override data descriptors with an instance attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case for old style objects (inheriting from nothing). Such objects do not have the `__class__` property. I think they do it this way to prevent errors. Example for Python 2.7:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(object):
    pass

a = A()
b = B()

print(dir(a)) # ['__doc__', '__module__']
print(dir(b)) # ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']

print(b.__class__) # <class '__main__.B'>
print(type(b))     # <class '__main__.B'>

#####################
# The intersting part
print(a.__class__) # __main__.A
print(type(a))     # <type 'instance'>


print(B.__class__) # <type 'type'>
print(type(B))     # <type 'type'>

print(type(A))      # <type 'classobj'>
#print(A.__class__) # AttributeError: class A has no attribute '__class__'
```

See this for further information:

- [Python type() or __class__, == or is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610993/python-type-or-class-or-is)
- [NewClassVsClassicClass](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)
- [Why does `type(myField)` return `<type 'instance'>` and not `<type 'Field'>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666856/why-does-typemyfield-return-type-instance-and-not-type-field)

**Note:** The given lines from cpython were changed in 2008 last time ([commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/68f5fbe94488b671ee6dfae74d918cc6a8eeca56)), so it really seems to be a compatibility thing or they just forgot about it.

Comment: While that makes sense - I was thinking about (forgot to mention that explicitly) about python 3.x and there are no old-style classes anymore.