# Correct way to write __repr__ function with inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, repr

I'm experimenting with OOP python and I wasn't sure about the `__repr__` function inheritance. Since the parent class function looked like this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    '''Returns representation of the object'''
    return("{}({!r})".format("Class name", self._param))
```

I wanted to know if it is better to use a generic approach (which could be suitable for children classes as well) like the following one:

```
def __repr__(self):
    '''Returns representation of the object'''
    return("{}({!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self._param))
```

or if it is a good practice to override the function in every class.

Also, please ignore the encoding part, since I'm leaving it behind.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's fine to override the method if you want don't want to extend it.

Comment: If all the child classes have the `_param` attribute, then it's quite safe for them to inherit that `__repr__` from the parent class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well the [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) has a special meaning in Pythons data model:

> ### `object.__repr__(self)`
>
> Called by the `repr()` built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. **If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)**. If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.
>
> This is typically used for debugging, so it is important that the representation is information-rich and unambiguous.

That means the string that is returned by `__repr__` should be usable to create another object just like it. So `__repr__` is something that *quite often* needs overriding, not because of the `__class__.__name__` but because the "state" has to be captured in the representation.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._param = param

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Returns representation of the object'''
        return("{}({!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self._param))
```

Then you absolutely should override the `__repr__` when you add parameters for `__init__`:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self._param = param1
        self._param2 = param2

    def __repr__(self):
        '''Returns representation of the object'''
        return("{}({!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self._param, self._param2))
```

But in case the `__repr__` of the superclass still **accurately** "describes" the subclass then there's no point overloading the `__repr__`:

```
class B(A):
     pass
```

---

However it's always a good choice to use `self.__class__.__name__` over hard-coding the class name, just in case you or someone else subclasses it.

Comment: You should take the ability for recreating an object from its repr recomendtion with a grain of salt: it is great for some kindof objects, still it was thought up at  a time when Pyhton's `input` would call "eval" on the value typed by the user: it was another mindset for interactive use of the Python language. Depending on the kind of object it is not really practical - and sometimes not even desirable - taht repr works this way.

Comment: @jsbueno It's more important for debugging (and when you post on StackOverflow). When the representation contains all necessary informations that define the instance then it's much easier to recreate a particular state or "see" what is going on.

Comment: I think `type(self).__name__` is a better choice for `__repr__` since it gives the *real* class name of `self`—that is what you want when you debug with `repr`—which might be different from its *virtual* class name, usually for proxy objects, such as those returned by `weakref.proxy` (cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757539/2326961)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes - - it is not just "ok", but it is what is more practical in almost every project and class hierarchy.

Actually, this is almost a perfect "text book example" of when to use class inheritance, and just let the code in the superclasses be reused.