# Python __repr__ for all member variables

Tags: python, string-formatting, repr

Implementing `__repr__` for a class `Foo` with member variables `x` and `y`, is there a way to automatically populate the string? Example that does not work:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({})".format(**self.__dict__)

>>> foo = Foo(42, 66)
>>> print(foo)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

And another:

```
from pprint import pprint
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({})".format(pprint(self.__dict__))

>>> foo = Foo(42, 66)
>>> print(foo)
{'x': 42, 'y': 66}
Foo(None)
```

Yes I could define the method as

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({x={}, y={}})".format(self.x, self.x)
```

but this gets tedious when there are many member variables.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use this as a mixin when I want something like that:

```
class SimpleRepr(object):
    """A mixin implementing a simple __repr__."""
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{klass} @{id:x} {attrs}>".format(
            klass=self.__class__.__name__,
            id=id(self) & 0xFFFFFF,
            attrs=" ".join("{}={!r}".format(k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.items()),
            )
```

It gives the class name, the (shortened) id, and all of the attributes.

Comment: Nice one! Real classy.

Comment: Why isn’t it the default `object.__repr__` implementation?

Comment: Note that one should probably use `type(self).__name__` instead of `self.__class__.__name__` to avoid returning virtual class names for proxy objects (cf. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757539/2326961)).

Comment: @Maggyero: If you're writing a proxy object, you probably shouldn't use this mixin for it at all. It'll give misleading results no matter which class name you pick.

Comment: (I'd recommend using the full ID instead of shortening it - people will make assumptions about what the number after that `@` sign means, and I think the shorter output isn't worth the confusion caused by shortening the ID.)

Comment: @Maggyero it's not the default it could lead to infinite recursion if there's circular references. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/885922

Answer (score 9):

I think you want something like this:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo({!r})".format(self.__dict__)
```

---

This will add `repr(self.__dict__)` in the string, using `!r` in a format specifier tells `format()` to call the item's `__repr__()`.

See the "Conversion field" here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

---

Based on [Ned Batchelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44595303/4482039), you can replace the line above by

```
return "{}({!r})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.__dict__)
```

for a more generic approach.

Comment: If `self` refers to itself, such an implementation will lead to an infinite loop such that you will have to filter `self.__dict__` first.

Answer (score 0):

Nice example!

for pretty output better to 
place simple `return "\n{!r}".format(self.__dict__)`
and in root full print `return "Class name: '{}' \n{!r}".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.__dict__)`

Answer (score 0):

Generally `__repr__` means that you can copy-paste the result and it can easily be used again for creating a new object. Therefore, the following may look a bit hacky but will do the job. Also, notice how we need to treat string type arguments differently from numeric types.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        repr_str = f"{self.__class__.__name__}"
        repr_str += '('
        
        for key, val in self.__dict__.items():
            val       = f"'{val}'" if isinstance(val, str) else val
            repr_str += f"{key}={val}, "
        
        return repr_str.strip(", ") + ')'


>>> foo = Foo(42, 66)
>>> print(foo)
Foo(x=42, y=66)

>>> foo2 = Foo("abc", "xyz")
>>> print(foo2)
Foo(x='abc', y='xyz')
```