# What does !r mean in Python?

Tags: python, f-string

I have found the following code in a project.

What does the `!r` part mean?

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"user={self.user!r}, variant={self.variant!r}"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default an f-string displays the result of calling [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#str) on the values inside the curly braces.  Specifying `!r` displays the result of calling [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) instead.

From the  [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

> The conversion field causes a type coercion before formatting. Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the **format**() method of the value itself. However, in some cases it is desirable to force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before calling **format**(), the normal formatting logic is bypassed.
>
> Three conversion flags are currently supported: '!s' which calls str() on the value, '!r' which calls repr() and '!a' which calls ascii().

Comment: I'll just provide pointers to some documentation:
[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595218/python-repr-for-all-member-variables) and [Python official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#s-r-and-a-are-redundant) to have them all!