# What is the type of the super object returned by super()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super):

> ```
> super( [ type [ , object-or-type ]] )
> ```
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of `type`. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class. The search order is same as that used by `getattr()` except that the `type` itself is skipped.
>
> If the second argument is omitted, the super object returned is
>   unbound.
>
> If the second argument is an object, `isinstance(obj, type)` must be
>   true.
>
> If the second argument is **a type**, `issubclass(type2, type)` must be
>   true (this is useful for classmethods).

1. If I am correct, a type is a class, and a class is a type. A class
   is an object, so a type is also an object.  Why does the quote
   distinguish the two cases when the second argument being an object 
   when it is a type?
2. When the second argument is a type, why is `issubclass(type2, type)`
   required to be true?
3. What is the type of the super object    returned by `super` in each of the three cases respectively? Or how do you determine the type of the super object returned by `super`?

   When the second argument is an object, because "The search order is same as that used by `getattr()` except that the `type` itself is skipped", I guessed that the type of the superobject returned by `super` function should be a subclass of any ancestry class of the first argument `type`, but I found that it is actually not by testing with `issubclass`. So did I misunderstand something?

Comment: `type` here references the *argument name*, not the `type()` built-in.

Comment: Does "type" in "If the second argument is a type" mean a specific type?

Comment: The type of the returned object is `super`.

Comment: @Tim Type can be anything that can have instances, it can be a metaclass or a class. For example `super()` won't work with `1` for example because `1` itself cannot act as an type and have its own instances. But it will work for a metaclass and class as both can have instances.

Comment: @user2357112: I didn't find type `super` in The Python Language Reference, in module `builtins`, or in module `types`. Where is its document?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: in my part 1, I am not sure how to tell the second argument is an object or a type, when it is both a type and an instance of another class.

Comment: The extent of its documentation is what you already found.

Comment: @user2357112 do you mean I miss it? Where is its documentation?

Comment: It's right there, in your link. The contents of your link constitute the entire documentation of the `super` type. There is no further documentation.

Comment: @user2357112 https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#super only describes the builtin function `super()`,  and I don't see type `super`.

Comment: the `__doc__` attribute is different when the 2nd argument is omitted

Comment: @Tim: The docs list it as a function, but it's a type. I didn't say it was particularly satisfying documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the word `type` with the [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) built-in. Here they simply references the first argument passed into `super()`.

What the documentation tells you is that *if* you pass in two arguments, then the second argument *either* has to be an instance of the first argument, *or* it has to be a subclass. In other words, either `isinstance(first_argument, second_argument)` or `issubclass(first_argument, second_argument)` must be true. *There is no other meaning here*.

Just like `int()` or `str()` or any of the other built-in types, the type of the object returned by calling `super()` *is that type*. There are no separate types returned for different arguments. See the [C source code defining the object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/typeobject.c#L7314-L7704).

The `super()` object implements a [`__getattribute__` hook](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/typeobject.c#L7361-L7434) that implements specific attribute behaviour. The documentation tells you that the *rules* for attribute lookups are the same as for `getattr()` (but with the documented MRO skip), but that does *not* mean that `super()` returns an ancestor class.

What actually happens is that `super().__getattribute__` takes the MRO of the second argument (either `type(instance).__mro__` or `cls.__mro__`, depending on wether `isinstance()` or `issubclass()` was true), find the first argument in that sequence and start testing for attributes after that. Because the MRO is scanned for the (type of) the second argument first, it does have to be findable, which is why the constraints are what they are.

In Pure Python, this is what `super()` does (simplified to focus on just the two argument behaviour):

```
def _supercheck(type_, obj):
    try:
        if issubclass(obj, type_):
            return obj
    except TypeError:
        # obj is not a type so issubclass throws a TypeError
        pass
    if isinstance(obj, type_):
        return type(obj)
    raise TypeError(
        "super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type")


class super_:
    def __init__(self, type_, obj):
        # simplified for the two-argument case
        self.type_ = type_
        self.obj = obj
        self.obj_type = _supercheck(type_, obj)

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '__class__':
            # __class__ should always come from this object, not
            # the represented MRO.
            return super().__getattribute__(name)

        # avoid infinite recursion issues
        sd = super().__getattribute__('__dict__')
        starttype = sd['obj_type']
        type_ = sd['type_']
        obj = sd['obj']

        mro = iter(starttype.__mro__)

        # skip past the start type in the MRO
        for tp in mro:
            if tp == type_:
                break

        # Search for the attribute on the remainder of the MRO
        for tp in mro:
            attrs = vars(tp)
            if name in attrs:
                res = attrs[name]
                # if it is a descriptor object, bind it
                descr = getattr(type(res), '__get__', None)
                if descr is not None:
                    res = descr(
                        res,
                        None if obj is starttype else obj,
                        starttype)
                return res

        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Comment: Nice implementation. Two remarks: 1. Like described in the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html?highlight=super#invocation-from-super), the slot `__self_class__` is equal to `__self__.__class__`, not `type(__self__)`, when the slot `__self__` is an instance of the slot `__thisclass__`. So you should replace `return type(obj)` with `return obj.__class__` (though they are equal most of the time).

Comment: 2. The method `__getattribute__` of superclasses before `object` is not looked up (you can subclass `super` *and* a custom class redefining `__getattribute__` to check this). So you should replace `return super().__getattribute__(name)` with `return object.__getattribute__(self, name)`.

Comment: @Maggyero: This is meant to be a readable Python representation of what `super()` does, and not aimed at behaving exactly the same way when subclassed. Does it really matter that much if `super().__getattribute__(name)` or `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` is used? For _code reading comprehension_, I much rather keep the former.

Comment: @Maggyero `__self__.__class__` is exactly the same thing as `type(__self__)`; both give you a reference to `Py_TYPE(self)`. I was using the idiomatic API. The are not just equal 'most of the time'. Yes, I am ignoring re-assignment of the name `type`, that's definitely out of scope here. So is overriding the `__class___` slot.

Comment: 2. I agree it is not that important, but it does not behave the same way when subclassed: `class A: def __getattribute__(self, name): return 'foo'; class B(super, A): pass; print(B(int).x)`. With `object.__getattribute__(self, name)` (the built-in `super`), you get `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'x'`, while with your `super` you get `foo`.

Comment: 1. There are cases where `type(instance)` and `instance.__class__` are different, cf. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53757539/2326961).

Comment: @Maggyero yes, I understand and already acknowledged that subclassing would let you inject a different `__getattribute__`, and yes, in theory you can replace the `__class__` slot on a class. However, this answer is an explanation of how `super()` works, illustrating the core principles. It is not meant to replicate edge case behaviour in exotic situations. I strongly feel that to do so would sacrifice clarity.

Comment: Fair enough. =)

Answer (score 2):

just for the point 3 about the type super in the 3 cases (2 first are similar):

```
class A(object):
    def sup(self):
        return (super(A, self))

class A1(object):
    def sup(self):
        return (super())


class B(object):      
    def sup(self):
        return (super(B))  

class C(A):
    def sup(self):
        return (super(A,C))      

a = A()
a_sup = a.sup()
print(type(a_sup))  #<class 'super'>
print(a_sup.__doc__)  #The most base type
print(a_sup.__self__)  #<__main__.A object at 0x7f9d0d2d8668>
print(a_sup.__self_class__) #<class '__main__.A'>
print(a_sup.__thisclass__)  #<class '__main__.A'>

print()  
a1 = A1()
a_sup = a1.sup()
print(type(a_sup))  #<class 'super'>
print(a_sup.__doc__)  #The most base type
print(a_sup.__self__)  #<__main__.A1 object at 0x7f9d0d2d86d8>
print(a_sup.__self_class__) #<class '__main__.A1'>
print(a_sup.__thisclass__) #<class '__main__.A1'>

print()    
b = B()
b_sup = b.sup()
print(type(b_sup))  #<class 'super'>
print(b_sup.__doc__) 
'''
super() -> same as super(__class__, <first argument>)
super(type) -> unbound super object
super(type, obj) -> bound super object; requires isinstance(obj, type)
super(type, type2) -> bound super object; requires issubclass(type2, type)
Typical use to call a cooperative superclass method:
class C(B):
    def meth(self, arg):
        super().meth(arg)
This works for class methods too:
class C(B):
    @classmethod
    def cmeth(cls, arg):
        super().cmeth(arg)
'''        

print(b_sup.__self__)  #None
print(b_sup.__self_class__)  #None
print(b_sup.__thisclass__)  #<class '__main__.B'>

print()
c=C()
c_sup = c.sup()
print(type(c_sup))  #<class 'super'>
print(c_sup.__doc__) #The most base type
print(c_sup.__self__) #<class '__main__.C'>
print(c_sup.__self_class__) #<class '__main__.C'>
print(c_sup.__thisclass__) #<class '__main__.A'>
```

Comment: Thanks. i am interested in the relation between type `super`, `type` and `object`. It is obvious that `super` must be an instance of `type`, and a subclass of `object`. Is there more relation between them?

Comment: `isinstance(a_sup, object)`  ==>  True,  `isinstance(a_sup, type)` ==> False, `issubclass(type(a_sup), type)` ==> False

Comment: @Tim: no, `super()` is *not* an instance of the first argument. Why should it be?