# What is meant by super() returning a proxy object?

Tags: python, super

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super),

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type.

The closest answer to what I need is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991579/what-is-the-type-of-the-super-object-returned-by-super):

> Just like `int()` or `str()` or any of the other built-in types, the type of the object returned by calling `super()` *is that type*.

My interpretation is, `super()` returns an object of the specified type. However, I'm not sure why the term 'proxy' is used, does it have to the with the design pattern named 'proxy'? For example,

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, phone, email):
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email

class Friend(Contact):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        super().__init__(phone, email)
```

For this case, as far as I'm concerned, `super().__init__(phone, email)` is equivalent to using `Contact.__init__(self, phone, email)`. That is, an instance of *Contact* is returned from `super()` for which we define a new attribute `name`, but I don't see how it would relate to that design pattern.

Comment: Yes, kind of related to the design pattern. You can `print(super())` and it will print out something like `<super: <class 'A'>, <A object>>`, so it is its own `super` type. It's just that when you type `super().whatever`, it delegates and returns the same thing as `the_superclass.whatever`. In other words, `__getattr__` is overridden. See the implementation at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/typeobject.c#L8758

Comment: "That is, an instance of Contact is returned from super() " it clearly isn't. `super()` returns an instance of `super`. This objects *acts as a proxy*.

Answer (score 4):

> That is, an instance of `Contact` is returned from `super()` for which
> we define a new attribute name

No, it doesn't. You can check by looking at `print(type(super()))`. `super()` returns an instance of `super`... `super` is actually a class! This objects *acts as a proxy*, i.e. it *proxies* the attribute lookup to the *next class in the method resolution order*. Here is how you might implement it in pure Python:

```
class SimpleSuper:
    def __init__(self, cls, instance):
        self.cls = cls
        self.instance = instance
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        mro = type(self.instance).mro()
        next_cls = mro[mro.index(self.cls) + 1]
        attribute = getattr(next_cls, name)
        if hasattr(attribute, "__get__"):
            return attribute.__get__(self.instance, self.cls)
        return attribute
```

Comment: This isn't exactly right; I think it should be `mro = self.instance.__class__.mro()`. [Demo here](https://tio.run/##fZLNaoQwFIX3PsVlujDSIJTuCl2Y@AazLCVYjZ2AZsREmD69vf4k/lQbUGK@c27ONWl@7O2uX/s@rzJjIHkLAIfOagnvECZhEEyAkSTaMuYZ/8O4ZylhFPgOp4gLnKQkCppWaUtC0zWyJSmFIoonWUhhv7hT8yM1P1OzIzVbqefEV1U3lbwOeEpdyBKEUFpZIYiRVUkhrwwFpY3NdC7n5oYx0Bgh9obv7bKTI3PTVflvaTNrW7/DGGkpXLd39LnyMX7ir3PwaY1d7ViIsR8hdmotH1ZMGRF84IOeQj6Iqx7BM7x8ev0QS311dgg@pySuxpzTa1UJt8yMEm@jcBnbE@KyamgYrbRdq5cN4llHNo1Q3/ayz94ZuKNeHd7@Mh2j6MjJz538fyc7d66vWt//Ag).

Comment: @kaya3 yep! Good catch

Answer (score 4):

The `super` call does not provide an instance of the superclass, but instead a *representation* for "`self` interpreted as a superclass instance". This object does not actually have the methods of the superclass, nor the attributes of `self`; rather, it serves to provide access to methods/attributes of the superclass/`self` – in other words, it is a proxy.

---

The result of the `super` call is an object that we can inspect:

```py
class Friend(Contact):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, email):
        self.name = name
        print("super():", super())
        print(super().name)  # should work since `self` has that attribute?
        super().__init__(phone, email)
```

This will provide an output such as the following:

```
super(): <super: <class 'Friend'>, <Friend object>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/Users/so/example.py", line 10, in __init__
    print(super().name)
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Notice how it only refers to the *actual* class `Friend` and the *actual* instance `<Friend object>`¹, yet does not have the attributes set on `self`. The `super` object is not an instance of `Contact`, neither a new one nor from casting `self`.

Instead, accessing a method on the `super` object results in an active search of the [Method Resolution Order](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) of `self`, which means looking at the superclasses of `Friend` and dynamically binding `self` to them. The `super` object itself never actually has these methods, it merely acts as a proxy to search them.

---

¹It is important that the `self` and `__class__` bound to `super` only satisfy `isinstance(self, __class__)` but not always `type(self) == __class__`. `self` defines the MRO, but `__class__` defines at what point to start searching the MRO. This ensures that `super` works properly when subclassing.