# What is super() when subclassing a list? How do I access the underlying list directly?

Tags: python, list, subclass, super, superclass

```
class Foo(list):
    def bar(self):
        return super().__getitem__(slice(None))
    
    def baz(self):
        return super()

a = Foo([0, 1, 2, 3])
print(a.bar()) # [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(a.baz()) # <super: <class 'Foo'>, <Foo object>>

# a.bar() provides a copy of the underlying list as can be seen from the fact that each result of a.bar() has a different id
print(id(a.bar())) # id1
print(id(a.bar())) # id2 != id1
```

I recently had a use case where I needed to subclass `list` and needed to access the underlying list from within the subclass (`Foo`). I thought `super()` would provide the underlying list, but it didn't. Instead I had to do `super().__getitem__(slice(None))` which provides a **copy** of the underlying list. How do I access the underlying list directly? And what am I missing in my understanding of `super()`?

Many thanks!

Comment: "and needed to access the underlying list from within the subclass" There is no "underlying list". The list **is the instance**, so in your methods, it will just be `self`

Comment: What circumstances require the underlying `list` but not the instance of `Foo`?

Comment: "Instead I had to do super().__getitem__(slice(None)) which provides a copy of the underlying list." Of course, because this is just the equivalent to `return self[:]` (using `super` here is totally pointless and unecessary), which *creates a shallow copy of the list*. Again, **you just want `self`**

Comment: `super()` is what it always is, it returns an object that proxies to the appropriate superclass method, generally used when *overriding* a method in a subclass (and it can also do a lot of interesting things in the case of cooperative multiple inheritance). It has nothing to do really with what you are trying to accomplish, in this context, it is a red herring

Comment: Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69907830/what-is-meant-by-super-returning-a-proxy-object/69917065#69917065) for an explanation of `super`, and of course, the indispensable [Super Considered Super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Will read the links.

@quamrana, I had to do `super(class, val).__getitem__(slice(None))` to get the Inheritance implementation of `ReversibleList` to work (see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/279555/239973). I couldn't find a better way, but maybe someone here will know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use your instance, as it's your list!

```
class Foo(list):
    pass


a = Foo([0, 1, 2, 3])
# __str__ method works fine
print(a)  # [0, 1, 2, 3]

for element in a:
    print(element)  # 0 1 2 3
```