# lack of understanding of the super() with parameters

Tags: python, init, super, superclass

i am new to programming, and based on what i've read so far,i thought that the super() method was viewed by python as super(**class**,self). so if i was inheriting from 2 parent classes, i could pass the class i want the super method to reference directly into super(). however when i do this, i get tracebacks that i cant understand.

the following 2 codes are what i tried that resulted in traceback

```
class Employee:
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = Employee.new_id
    Employee.new_id += 1

class User:
  def __init__(self, username, role="Customer"):
    self.username = username
    self.role = role


class Admin(Employee,User):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Employee,self).__init__()
    super(User,self).__init__(self,self.id,'admin')
    

e1 = Employee()
e2 = Employee()
e3 = Admin()
------------------
class Employee:
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = Employee.new_id
    Employee.new_id += 1

class User:
  def __init__(self, username, role="Customer"):
    self.username = username
    self.role = role


class Admin(Employee,User):
  def __init__(self):
    Employee.__init__()
    User.__init__(self,self.id,'admin')
    

e1 = Employee()
e2 = Employee()
e3 = Admin()
```

i want to understand why the code above results in tracebacks, because from what i understood, i am still calling the init method of the parentclass in each one.

```
class Employee:
  new_id = 1
  def __init__(self):
    self.id = Employee.new_id
    Employee.new_id += 1

class User:
  def __init__(self, username, role="Customer"):
    self.username = username
    self.role = role


class Admin(Employee,User):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    User.__init__(self.id,'admin')
```

Comment: `super()` is a built-in function that inherits all attributes from parent class.

Comment: If you want to explicitly call methods on each parent class, then simply do so: `Employee.__init__(self); User.__init__(self, ...)`.  `super()` has nothing to do with this sort of usage.

Comment: "so if i was inheriting from 2 parent classes, i could pass the class i want the super method to reference directly into super()." **no**. That is absolutely not what that means. Watch the following for a really good explanation of what `super` is actually doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: ", i get tracebacks that i cant understand." As an aside, if you are getting errors, **always post the full error message**

Comment: [Here is an example of how to implement `super` yourself, without the zero-argument magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69917065/5014455)