# Get just a class name without module, etc

Tags: python

I'm probably overlooking something simple.  Given an instance of a class, I'd like to get just the class name.  For example:

```
class Foooo: pass
instance = Foooo()

print("instance.__class__ = "+str(instance.__class__))
print("Just the class name: "+str(instance.__class__).split(".")[-1][:-2])
```

This gives the following output:

```
instance.__class__ = <class '__main__.Foooo'>
Just the class name: Foooo
```

Is there something simpler than

```
str(instance.__class__).split(".")[-1][:-2]?
```

I'm in Python 3.2 if that helps...

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/510972/2099613. You can find more explanations including the preferred solution `type(instance).__name__` there

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
instance.__class__.__name__
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I should have realized that!