# Getting the class a variable resides in

Tags: python, inheritance

Lets say I have something like this -

```
class A(object):
    c = C()

class B(A):
    pass

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def get_parent_class(self):
        # This should return B
```

How would I implement `get_parent_class`, so that it will work as following -

```
B.c.get_parent_class() # Returns the class type B (not the instance b!)
```

Is this even possible?

I basically have a parent class (class `A` in our example), which contains a variable (var `c` in the example). I then have a child-class (class `B` which inherits `A`)

I want to use functions that `C` exposes on `B`, but in order to be used properly, I need `C` to know it's running on `B`

(Hope I didn't complicate things in the last explanation...)

**Edit -** 
Please note that I'm not trying to get the class of `C`, that's an easy `c.__class__`. I need the class holding `c`

Thanks!

Comment: `c = C()` raises an exception because `C` is not defined yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the class name of an instance in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python)

Comment: @Stiffo : not a duplicate OP wants the class name of a class *containing* c, not the class name of C nor any of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot do that.

B.c just returns a reference to a C object. Same object can be a member of a list, of an instance of another class (say D) and of another class (say E)

Just add to your example :

```
class D:
    def __init__(self, c):
        self.c = c
class E:
    c = C()
```

Then :

```
>>> c = B.c
>>> E.c = c
>>> d = D(c)
>>> c.a = 1
>>> B.c.a
1
>>> d.c.a
1
>>> E.c.a
1
```

At that point, c object itself does not know that it belongs to B, d and E. And what should `c.get_parent_class()` return ? How to decide between B and E ?

You could try to make C aware of its container :

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, clazz):
        self.clazz = clazz

    def get_parent_class(self):
        return self.clazz

class A(object):
    c = C(A)
```

You would get `A.c.get_parent_class()` giving `<class '__main__.A'>` but as it would be the same object, `B.c.get_parent_class()` will also give`<class '__main__.A'>` ...

Answer (score -1):

You could take a look at the `__bases__` attribute of your object. It returns a tuple of base classes for an object.

You can see it in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__).

Answer (score -1):

You can get the class from the name attribute, example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x = itertools.count(0)
>>> x.__class__.__name__
'count'
```

Or this way:

```
>>> type(x).__name__
'count'
```