# How to get a model name from the instance as a string in Django?

Tags: python, django, string, django-models, model

How can I get a model name as a "string" from a model instance. 
I know you can do something like `type(model_instance)`
but this is returning the class itself as an object `<Model_Name: >` not as a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the class name of an instance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
from user.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(tel='1234567890', password='YKH0000000')
print(user._meta.model)
<class 'user.models.User'>
print(user._meta.model.__name__)
User
print(user.__class__.__name__)
User
```

Answer (score 1):

To stay close to the question, `type(instance).__name__` is a valide answer (which is the one given in [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python))

So using @Ykh example:

```
from user.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user(tel='1234567890', password='YKH0000000')
print(type(user).__name__)
User
```

Answer (score 0):

With `__name__`, you can get a model name in `str` type as shown below:

```py
from .models import MyModel
              
print(MyModel.__name__) # MyModel
```

Answer (score -3):

By defining the **str** or **unicode** method ?

Comment: defining str gives a string name for the "model_instance" not the model