# Issues printing the class, name and accuracy score of the voting classifier

Tags: python, class, printing, scikit-learn, classification

I would like to train a voiting classifer in SciKit-Learn with three different classifiers. I'm having issues with the final step, which is printing the final accuracy scores of the classifiers.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

log_clf=LogisticRegression()
rnd_clf=RandomForestClassifier()
svm_clf=SVC()

voting_clf=VotingClassifier(estimators=[('lr',log_clf),('rf',rnd_clf),('svc',svm_clf)],voting='hard')
voting_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am getting errors when I run the following code:

```
for clf in (log_clf, rnd_clf, svm_clf, voting_clf):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_predict=clf.predict(X_test)
    print(clf._class_._name_,accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

When I run this chunk of code I get the following:

```
AttributeError: 'LogisticRegression' object has no attribute '_class_'
```

I am assuming that calling '*class*'is a bit outdated, so I changed class to 'classes_':

```
for clf in (log_clf, rnd_clf, svm_clf, voting_clf):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    print(clf.classes_._name_,accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

When I run this chunk of code I get the following:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_name_'
```

When I remove '*name*' and run the following code, I still get an error:

```
for clf in (log_clf, rnd_clf, svm_clf, voting_clf):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)
    print(clf.classes_,accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

Error:

```
 NameError: name 'accuracy_score' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why accuracy_score is not defined seeing that imported the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first error about *class*, you need to have two underscores here.

Change

```
print(clf._class_._name_,accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

to:

```
print(clf.__class__.__name__, accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

See this question for other ways to get the name of an object in python:

- [Getting the class name of an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance)

Now for the second error about `'accuracy_score'` not defined, this happens when you have not imported the `accuracy_score` correctly. But I can see that in your code you have imported the `accuracy_score`. So are you sure that you are executing the line `print(clf.__class__.__name__, accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))` in the same file? or in any different file?