# How can I make the OOP code print my classes objects name?

Tags: python, oop

I've tried to make an OOP based program in python. I gave it an object to work with and tried to make it print the name, but its not working.

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("this is a human")
    def name(self, name):
        print("this is {}".format(bob.name))

bob = human("bob")
```

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the class name of an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance)

Comment: @ai.jennetta It does not.

Comment: @ai.jennetta thanks for the recommendation, but it either doesn't help me at all, as I can't understand it, or it's in a format where it's difficult for me to understand

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the desired behaviour? Perhaps you want one of the following: 1. Print `human` on initializing (`bob = human("bob")`). 2. Print `bob` on initializing. 3. Print `bob` on calling `name` method (`bob.name()`).

Comment: I'm not sure why my question got downvoted, could someone explain why they downvoted so i could fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never assigned the passed name to the object. Try:

```
class human:

    def __init__(self, name):
        print("this is a human")
        self.name = name
    def print_name(self):
        print("this is {}".format(self.name))
bob = human("bob")
bob.print_name()
```

Answer (score 3):

Beyond the answers you already received (which solve your problem), I'd suggest not having a method that prints the name. Rather, you should have a `__str___` dunder method that defines the object's behavior when an instance is printed.

```
class human:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

person = human("bob")

print(person)
```

```
'bob'
```

You can also define the object's behavior when the instance name is entered in the console, for instance just running the line

```
>>> person
```

You can do it with `__repr__`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'when entering the instance name in the console: {self.name}'
```

This will print:

```
when entering the instance name in the console: bob
```

This appears more pythonic to me than having a method that simply prints the name.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're never *storing* the name on the instance, where would it get the name from? Your `__init__` needs to do something along the lines of `self.name = name`
2. the `name` method and attribute are going to conflict, the latter will shadow (hide) the former, and it should look up whatever attribute its using on `self`

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of things to update in the code:

- bob is an instance which is not defined at `human` class
- notice that init, name functions expect external param but you never use it in the function. (in self. = name)
  in order to use it:
  define a var in the class named 'name' and update you function to:

```
class human:
    _name = ""
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("this is a human")
        self._name = name
    def name(self):
        print("this is "+ self._name)

bob = human("bob")
bob.name()
```

- `bob = human("bob")` only init function and you should call `bob.name()` in order to call the print-name function