# Getting the name of the current class in a class

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way for me to print the class name itself, not the full info that `__class__` gives you?
Code:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def class_name(self):
        print(f"Current class: [Class name here as an f-string]")
```

In this case, `MyClass().class_name()` will print the class name "MyClass".

Comment: You mean `self.__class__.__name__`?

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, that helps too! Both you and someone else helped! Thank you also! But idk how to close my question, or just leave an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Do you want the name of the class the method is in, or the name of the type of `self`? They might not be the same if you later create a subclass.

Comment: @Brad Huh, I'm surprised no one mentioned `type(self).__name__` on that question, since `self.__class__` can be duped. I'll post my own answer I guess.

Comment: Better duplicate: [Getting the class name of an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510972/4518341) - this one mentions `type(self).__name__`