# What is the type of the object that instantiates classes in python?

Tags: python, class, types, docstring

I have a problem that I don't even know how to search for. Look at this simple class as an example:

```
class Student(object):
    def _init_(self):
        self.id = 0
    
    def inc(self):
        self.id += 1
 
std_gen = Student
```

What is the type of `std_gen`?
I tried:

```
print(type(std_gen))
```

and I got this:

```
<class 'type'>
```

I need to find it's type and add it to a docstring. I can't even find `something` that returns `True` with `isinstance(std_gen, something)`

Edit: I found `isinstance(std_gen, type)` returns `True` but that barely makes sense in a docstring. What does that mean?

Comment: `std_gen` is just another name for `Student`, you did not actually instantiate the class (which would be written `Student()`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance

Comment: It can't be the same since `std_gen` acts as a constructor and what `std_gen()` returns is an instance of that class.

Comment: @PavanChandaka Could you explain a bit? I looked through the page and couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Student is an instance of type 'type'. See metaclass for more information. So type(Student) is 'type'. So

```
s = Student()
std_gen = Student
type(s) // <class 'Student'>
type(std_gen) // <class 'type'>
```

To sum up, s is instance of Student, Student is instance of type and stu_gen is just alias of Student.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the solution that you're looking for.

```
print(type(std_gen()))
```