# How to print the exception string in <class> for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I'm using Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10.  I have the following code:

```py
import # all the necessary modules

try:
    # do something
except WebDriverException:
    print(sys.exc_info()[0])
```

Upon the exception, I receive the following:

```py
<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException'>
```

How do I get `print()` to output only the string within `<class>`?:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `except WebDriverException as exc: print(type(exc))`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe That prints out the same exact thing as `print(sys.exc_info()[0])`.  I'm looking to only out put the string after <class>.

Comment: `.__name__`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that as well.  The first answer below, was modified with `__name__`, but it only gives `SessionNotCreatedException`.  Which is close, but not the exact string.

Comment: Then see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/2020014/3001761 - what's the *context* here, what are you using that for, and what research have you done already?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've done searches and tried several answers from various threads on here and websites.  Unfortunately I didn't find the solution.  That's why I asked my specific question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to *show your research*, then - if you've tried `__name__`, `__qualname__` etc. then include that information. [Sharing your research helps everyone.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @jonrsharpe. I've modified the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full path of an exception, use the **inspect.getmodule** method to get the package name and use **type(..).__name __** to get the class name.

```
except WebDriverException as ex: 
    print (type(ex).__name__)
```

For the full name, try

```
import inspect
.....
print(inspect.getmodule(ex).__name__, type(ex).__name__, sep='.')
```

To keep it simple, you can just parse the string you already have

```
print(str(sys.exc_info()[0])[8:-2]) # selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException
```

Comment: I tried that.  It doesn't print the string.  Instead it prints the same thing that `sys.exc_info()[1]` would output.

Comment: answer updated: `type(ex).__name__`

Comment: That's much closer.  It prints `SessionNotCreatedException`.  Was hoping for the full string though.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  The `inspect` module usage worked perfectly.

Comment: Why not `type(ex).__module__`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try this

```
import # anything

try:
   # something
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: I tried this from the first answer.  As I commented there, this produces the same output as `sys.exc_info()[1]`, not the string I'm looking for in my question.