# Do all magic private functions/properties in Python have an equivalent public function/property?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't believe in calling the magic functions or properties directly from outside of the class because they are private to the class and it's not the caller's responsibility to know about them but I can't find the equivalent public functions/properties.

If I have a class:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

def B:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

my_classes = {'one':A(), 'two':B()}
```

As an instance, how do I call the

```
my_val = some_func(input)
instance_type = my_classes[my_val]
instance_type.__name__
```

Comment: I have a number of classes and I have a function that gets the right class and I want to pass the name of the chosen class as a parameter to a function.

Comment: It's not a function ok. But it's a private property by naming convention.

Comment: Using `__name__` is the correct way to get the name of a class, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing private functions/attributes with functions/attributes with double underscores before AND after the name.  There is nothing wrong with accessing attributes with double underscores before and after the attribute.  They are just labelled like that to avoid collisions, but it's legitimate to use, though something like `__getattr__()` probably doesn't make much sense to call outside of the class.  But `__name__` and `__class__` are both okay to access.

I believe what you are thinking of is prefixing a function or attribute with double underscore.  This will mangle the name and is not meant to be used/called outside the class.  The difference is that they don't have a double underscore suffix.

```
class T():
   def __priv(self):
      pass

   def __special__(self):
      pass

   __attr = None

print(dir(T()))
```

You should see `_T__priv`, `_T__attr`, and `__special__`.  So the double underscore before AND after will not mangle.  I'm not sure making your own `__someattribute__` is the best idea, but the builtin ones for sure are available to you to use.