# How do I get the module and class name of an object as a string in Python?

Tags: python

In Python, I can write

```
from some_module.some_submodule import SomeClass

foo = SomeClass()
module_and_class = str(type(foo))
```

and the value of `module_and_class` is

```
<class 'some_module.some_submodule.SomeClass'>
```

How do I get just `'some_module.some_submodule.SomeClass'`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the class name of an instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/510972/6045800)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want some combination of:

```
klass = type(foo)

print(klass.__module__, klass.__qualname__)
```

So, reconstructing it yourself:

```
module_and_class = f"{klass.__module__}.{klass.__qualname__}"
```