# Pass class name as a variable in Python

Tags: python

I have the below sample code:

```
def sample(cls):
    class a():
        def __init__(self):
            self.value='a'
    class b():
        def __init__(self):
            self.value='b'
    def __init__(self):
       self.cls=cls()
    return self.value

sample(b)
```

I have defined 2 classes in the sample code. I want to be able to define the class name in a  function. So the above code will return 'b'. Is there a way to do it? The above code will give me the error:

> 'str' object is not callable

Comment: What's the use case and aside from that are there syntax errors in your code. Can you please add more information to your question? :)

Comment: You can't literally pass the class name, because the class names are not defined outside of the function.  You could pass a string, and do `if cls=='a':` / `return a()` / `else:` / `return b()`, or even have a dictionary to do the mapping.

Comment: What about `__name__`  to get the [class name of the instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one option:

```
def sample(cls):
    class a():
        def __init__(self):
            self.value='a'
    class b():
        def __init__(self):
            self.value='b'
    return {'a': a, 'b': b}[cls]()

print(sample('b'))
```

Or, if you really want to use the class name, you could define the classes outside of the function:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value='a'
class b():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value='b'

def sample(cls):
    return cls()

print(sample(b))
```

Not sure what the advantage would be over just calling `b()`.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Writing the class outside of the function is a better approach to this.